# How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, sorting

I'm a bit out of my depth here and I'm hoping this is actually possible.

I'd like to be able to call a function that would sort all the items in my list alphabetically.

I've been looking through the jQuery UI for sorting but that doesn't seem to be it. Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery

Comment: Check out [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy) or [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/sortBy).

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You do *not* need jQuery to do this...

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if(typeof ul == "string")
    ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  // Idiot-proof, remove if you want
  if(!ul) {
    alert("The UL object is null!");
    return;
  }

  // Get the list items and setup an array for sorting
  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var vals = [];

  // Populate the array
  for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

  // Sort it
  vals.sort();

  // Sometimes you gotta DESC
  if(sortDescending)
    vals.reverse();

  // Change the list on the page
  for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}
```

Easy to use...

```
sortUnorderedList("ID_OF_LIST");
```

**[Live Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/De8Ku/)**

Comment: One problem that I found with this approach is that, since it's only the text that's being moved around, if you associate data to the DOM nodes using jQuery.data prior to sorting, those associations are now pointing to the wrong nodes after the sort.

Comment: @Rudism If you're using jQuery, refer to SolutionYogi's answer below

Comment: Note that `var lis = ul.children` should suffice here (and is far more efficient). Also note that `lis[i].textContent` is preferred (as it's more efficient and get's the actual text).

Comment: Attention down-voters: I would like to encourage you to run some tests before you make a haphazard judgement. This is not as bad as it looks, believe me!

Comment: Moving elements with innerHTML is a bad solution because they are not the same elements after sorting. All existing references to the elements are lost. All event listeners bound from JavaScript are lost. It would be better to store the elements instead of innerHTML, use a sort function (vals.sort(function(a, b) {return b.innerHTML < a.innerHTML;})) and appendChild to move elements.

Comment: Buhuuu innerHTML ! Don't use that. It's Microsoft Proprietary stuff and was never acknowledged by the W3C.

Comment: IMHO this is a horrible answer.  It's perfectly possible to rearrange DOM nodes without serialising them and deserialising them again, and without destroying any attached properties and/or events.

Comment: If you want to sort `<li><a href="1.html">One<a></li>` type lists by the content within the `<a></a>` tag, simply change this line `var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");` to `var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("a");`

Comment: This works fine if you have anything but text inside your list-items. Otherwise it gets confused and doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: It really only makes sense if you are just using one tag inside of another but if you are using A tags you cannot simply search for the a tags because you could have some lited items that are not links.

Comment: ... but if you were to use jQuery, how would you do it?

Comment: This answer is disastrous for DOM elements that have state attached (i.e events and data). The functions `Node.removeChild()` and and `Node.insertBefore()` exist for a reason.

Comment: This is a more robust answer that preserves data and attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery

Answer (score 352):

Something like this:

```
var mylist = $('#myUL');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

From this page: http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Above code will sort your unordered list with id 'myUL'.

OR you can use a plugin like TinySort. https://github.com/Sjeiti/TinySort

Comment: Can the last line be replaced with $(listitems).appendTo(mylist); ?

Comment: H. L. Menken has a quote that describes this solution: "For every problem, there is a solution that is simple, elegant, and wrong." This process runs in O(n^2) time. It's not noticable with relatively short lists, but on a list containing over 100 elements it takes 3-4 seconds to finish sorting.

Comment: @Nathan: About "For every problem, there is a solution that is simple, elegant, and wrong." - well, a wrong solution is not elegant.

Comment: Something can be elegant and intriguing to watch, but still fail. Elegance doesn't imply success.

Comment: This solution is not wrong. It answers the question. The OP did not specify that he needed to sort a list of more than 100 items. If his list will never be longer than 100 items this solution is perfectly acceptable. +1 for pointing out that the solution is slow, -1 for declaring a solution that meets the requirements as 'wrong'.

Comment: This solution is more general - if I just wanted to sort a list of values, I would use Josh's solution.  But if I want to sort an array of DOM elements based on some attribute of those elements, this solution is far superior.

Comment: This worked for me but I did add `trim()` to handle whitespace. `return $(a).text().toUpperCase().trim().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase().trim())`

Comment: Documentation for `localeCompare` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: @NathanStrong: Which process runs in O(n^2) time?

Comment: In this case there is no need to empty or detach the existing list. Can someone explain me why? I tried with a test file and you don't get duplicated list items, you get same but ordered. Beyond that, it works perfectly.

Comment: Never mind, I've already found the answer in JQuery API Documentation site. This is what I was looking for "If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)". Source: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Thanks for that link to TinySort, made my list sorting a snap.

Answer (score 102):

```
$(".list li").sort(asc_sort).appendTo('.list');
//$("#debug").text("Output:");
// accending sort
function asc_sort(a, b){
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;    
}

// decending sort
function dec_sort(a, b){
    return ($(b).text()) > ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

live demo : http://jsbin.com/eculis/876/edit

Comment: This is the best answer. I even like it in one single line like this: `$(".list li").sort(function(a, b){return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text());}).appendTo('.list');`. One remark though: `.text()` should be `.text().toUpperCase()`

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in IE whilst PatrickHecks answer below works in all browsers.

Comment: Beware of the selector! ".list li" will select all descendent LI tags, not just the immediate children.

Comment: @DougDomeny is right. Better to call `$(".list").children()`, if possible, or set up the selector with immediate child relationship like `$(".list > li")`

Comment: BTW Here's a link to a fiddle i made using this answer. I set up the code as an all-in-one function:

http://jsfiddle.net/mroncetwice/t0whh6fL/

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. It does not return 0 when text is same.

Comment: improvements: `$(".list>li").sort...` to avoid mistakenly moving grand-children. 
`function asc_sort(a, b){return a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText);}` for much faster run.

Answer (score 42):

To make this work work with all browsers including Chrome you need to make the callback function of sort() return -1,0 or 1.

see http://inderpreetsingh.com/2010/12/01/chromes-javascript-sort-array-function-is-different-yet-proper/

```
function sortUL(selector) {
    $(selector).children("li").sort(function(a, b) {
        var upA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var upB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(selector);
}
sortUL("ul.mylist");
```

Comment: Shouldn't all the li elements be removed from ul.myList before appending the sorted li elements ?

Comment: @Daud, the LI elements don't need to be explicitly removed.

Comment: Using .localeCompare would be an improvement for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @DougDomeny, why don't the li elements need to be explicitly removed?

Comment: @bowserm, the appendTo method moves the DOM elements rather than copying them.

Answer (score 37):

If you are using jQuery you can do this:

```js
$(function() {

  var $list = $("#list");

  $list.children().detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
  }).appendTo($list);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li>delta</li>
  <li>cat</li>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>cat</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>gamma</li>
  <li>gamma</li>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>cat</li>
  <li>delta</li>
  <li>bat</li>
  <li>cat</li>
</ul>
```

Note that returning 1 and -1 (or 0 and 1) from the compare function [is absolutely wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/87015).

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic, amazing,  marvelous !!

Answer (score 8):

@SolutionYogi's answer works like a charm, but it seems that using $.each is less straightforward and efficient than directly appending listitems :

```
var mylist = $('#list');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();

listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})

mylist.empty().append(listitems);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/2567/)

Comment: $('#list').empty() --> mylist.empty() would be better. No need to touch the DOM again.

Comment: Absolutely, I just fixed it!

Comment: This does not work in Internet Explorer (tested with version 10).

Comment: I just tested with IE11 and in fact, it doesn't work. But SolutionYogi's code didn't work neither under IE11… Did that work for you?

Answer (score 6):

improvement based on [Jeetendra Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838790/3356679)'s answer

```
$('ul.menu').each(function(){
    $(this).children('li').sort((a,b)=>a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText)).appendTo(this);
});
```

why i consider it an improvement:

1. using `each` to support running on more than one ul
2. using `children('li')` instead of `('ul li')` is important because we only want to process direct children and not descendants
3. using the arrow function `(a,b)=>` just looks better (IE not supported)
4. using vanilla `innerText` instead of `$(a).text()` for speed improvement
5. using vanilla `localeCompare` improves speed in case of equal elements (rare in real life usage)
6. using `appendTo(this)` instead of using another selector will make sure that even if the selector catches more than one ul still nothing breaks

Comment: Resource friendly solution, highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do this myself, and I wasnt satisfied with any of the answers provided simply because, I believe, they are quadratic time, and I need to do this on lists hundreds of items long.

I ended up extending jquery, and my solution *uses* jquery, but could easily be modified to use straight javascript.

I only access each item twice, and perform one linearithmic sort, so this should, I think, work out to be a lot faster on large datasets, though I freely confess I could be mistaken there:

```
sortList: function() {
   if (!this.is("ul") || !this.length)
      return
   else {
      var getData = function(ul) {
         var lis     = ul.find('li'),
             liData  = {
               liTexts : []
            }; 

         for(var i = 0; i<lis.length; i++){
             var key              = $(lis[i]).text().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ""),
             attrs                = lis[i].attributes;
             liData[key]          = {},
             liData[key]['attrs'] = {},
             liData[key]['html']  = $(lis[i]).html();

             liData.liTexts.push(key);

             for (var j = 0; j < attrs.length; j++) {
                liData[key]['attrs'][attrs[j].nodeName] = attrs[j].nodeValue;
             }
          }

          return liData;
       },

       processData = function (obj){
          var sortedTexts = obj.liTexts.sort(),
              htmlStr     = '';

          for(var i = 0; i < sortedTexts.length; i++){
             var attrsStr   = '',
                 attributes = obj[sortedTexts[i]].attrs;

             for(attr in attributes){
                var str = attr + "=\'" + attributes[attr] + "\' ";
                attrsStr += str;
             }

             htmlStr += "<li "+ attrsStr + ">" + obj[sortedTexts[i]].html+"</li>";
          }

          return htmlStr;

       };

       this.html(processData(getData(this)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the list in an array, use JavaScript's `.sort()`, which is by default alphabetical, then convert the array back to a list.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>alpha</li>
    <li>gamma</li>
    <li>beta</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
function sort(ul) {
    var ul = document.getElementById(ul)
    var liArr = ul.children
    var arr = new Array()
    for (var i = 0; i < liArr.length; i++) {
        arr.push(liArr[i].textContent)
    }
    arr.sort()
    arr.forEach(function(content, index) {
        liArr[index].textContent = content
    })
}

sort("list")
```

JSFiddle Demo https://jsfiddle.net/97oo61nw/

Here we are push all values of `li` elements inside `ul` with specific `id` (which we provided as function argument) to array `arr` and sort it using [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method which is sorted alphabetical by default. After array `arr` is sorted we are loop this array using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and just replace text content of all `li` elements with sorted content