# Sort Unordered List with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at the stackoverflow thread:

[How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/jquery-sort-list-items-alphabetically)

but for my scenario, I have the hierachy:

```
<ul><li><a href="http://www.google.com.au">NAME_TO_SORT_ON</a></li></ul>
```

Based on this set-up, how can I modify the solution from thread mentioned here to cater for my scenario which has a  tag as I would like to sort on all the name found in NAME_TO_SORT_ON?

Thanks.

Comment: If you sort it, it will be an ordered list, not an unordered list...

Comment: Thanks NickFitz but this is what I am after. I cannot change the tags so require a means to sort an unordered list.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a jQuery-based solution for this, because once you start getting into multiple DOM levels (e.g. sorting siblings at one level based on the contents of elements at a deeper level) the simple sort mechanism breaks down. It's an extremely *rough* solution - essentially blowing away the existing HTML and replacing it in raw text mode with other HTML. We can do better by actually shuffling the DOM elements around:

```
function sort(list, key) {
    $($(list).get().reverse()).each(function(outer) {
        var sorting = this;
        $($(list).get().reverse()).each(function(inner) {
            if($(key, this).text().localeCompare($(key, sorting).text()) > 0) {
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(sorting.parentNode.removeChild(sorting), this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

To use it, we pass in a selector to the list and a selector to use to locate the key we want to sort on:

```
<ul class="toBeSorted">
    <li><a href="...">sort me</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    sort('ul.toBeSorted>li', 'a');

    //we want to sort the <li>'s in ul.toBeSorted;
    //and we want to use the text of the first and only <a>
    //in each item as the sort key
</script>
```

Comment: Rex, tried it out and unfortunately getting an error:object required on the sort() call. Didn't realise but my ul is actually inside a div with id of refmenu. So my new sort call is as follows: sort('#refmenu>ul.platsys>li', 'a');

Is this call correct and any ideas as to what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils you are including the jQuery library before `sort()` is called?

Comment: Surely am Rex. Firstly, am I using the new sort parameters correctly to include div id of refmenu? 2) Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? FYI, I am using jQuery 1.3.2 version.

Comment: This works beautifully, please mark as the right answer