# Lists alphabetical ordered by javascript

Tags: sorting

I have this code:

```
<h2 class="title">A-Z Categories</h2>
<div id="cat-abc">

<div class="cat-top">
<ul>
<li>January</li>
<li>May</li>
<li>November</li>
<li>August</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="cat-top">
<ul>
<li>March</li>
<li>June</li>
<li>September</li>
<li>December</li>
</ul>
</div>


</div>
```

I would like to sort this items alphabetically.How can I Lists alphabetical ordered by javascript ?

August
December
January
June

March
May
November
September
Thanks.

Comment: Sort what, exactly?  Can you at least provide what the expected output is?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535744/sort-unordered-list-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would like to output looks like sorting items alphabetically:

August
December
January
June

March
May
November
September