# jQuery arrange li order base on #ID

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
<li id="project_25">Proj Something</li>
<li id="project_26">Proj Blah</li>
<li id="project_27">Proj Else</li>
<li id="project_31">Proj More</li>
...
</ul>
```

Is there a way to arrange these LIs, reverse their order, based on the LI ID?

Something like:

```
<ul>
<li id="project_31">Proj More</li>
<li id="project_27">Proj Else</li>
<li id="project_26">Proj Blah</li>
<li id="project_25">Proj Something</li>
...
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This method can probably be applied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/jquery-sort-list-items-alphabetically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var arr = $('li').get();    
arr.reverse();

$.each(arr, function(i,v){
    $('ul').append(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code given below:

```
var mylist = $('ul');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

I found this [here](http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/).

HTH

Comment: This will rearrange on alphabetical order. I'll try to modify it and let you know

Comment: That was just a sample to give you an idea. Instead of getting text() try to get the number (by splitting it) and then compare it. HTH

Comment: Sorry this one works only for text not IDs, I was unable to make it works with attr