# Filter jquery split list

Tags: jquery, list, filter, split

see: http://jasondaydesign.com/index2.html

I am using easylistsplitter.js to layout the portfolio items. Unfortunately, my filter does not work on all of the items. It only filters the first column.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Thought: maybe specifying your question a little more wouldn't be a bad idea ;-)

Comment: Yes, like: what is easylistsplitter.js supposed to do, what does it do instead, why is that wrong, what filter are you using, is there a code sample that you can post, which 'column' do you mean...

Comment: jquery.easylistsplitter.js - http://pastebin.com/jpZknPLt
filterable.js - http://pastebin.com/ZCda0Y7Q

easylistsplitter splits lists into columns - which it does great. Unfortunately, I am unable to filter the list items by class. When I use the filter, it only works on the first column of a list split by easylistsplitter. I'm assuming this is because it splits the list into multiple lists, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand how you are trying to use the listsplitter along with the masonry plugin...

The masonry plugin sets up the layout and splits the layout into how ever many columns you want. If you look at your layout page, masonry has split the layout into 4 columns: `#primary.listCol1`, `.listCol2`, `.listCol3` and `.listCol4.last`. So applying the listsplitter afterwards doesn't work because the list is already split.

If you are trying to sort the list, you could check out the [tinysort](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort) plugin or if you just want a nice short script, the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/jquery-sort-list-items-alphabetically/1134983#1134983) will need some slight modification.

---

Update: I was looking at the filterable script, but I couldn't find a nice easy solution. But I did find [this filterable tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/) which seems a bit easier to understand (to me). I modified it slightly to make the animation the same as your filterable script and this was the result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul#portfolio-filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#portfolio-filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
      $('.portfolio li.hidden').animate({ width: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 1000 ).removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('.portfolio li').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
          $(this).animate({ width: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 1000 ).addClass('hidden');
        } else {
          $(this).animate({ width: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 1000 ).removeClass('hidden');
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

You shouldn't have to change anything except to replace the "jquery.filterablepack.js" contents with the above code.

Comment: sorry - not using masonry for layout - using the easylist splitter for a masonry style layout. This filtering effect allows me to have toggles. It's 2 different layouts (you helped me with masonry and I'm trying to determine which is best.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with some filterable code I found, because I couldn't get the one you had to work.

Comment: Fudgey - you are a wealth of knowledge. I appreciate all of your help. Now I have to figure out which I like better - the list filter with toggle, or the masonry filter without toggle...