# How do I use jQuery for client-side sorting of div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to allow the user of a web app to sort results of a query without a server call.  I'm looking for the usual type of click-the-header-to-sort-based-on-the-column.

However, I'm not working with an actual table. I'll be manipulating div tags based on contents.  Is there a jQuery method to facilitate this?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the code this jQuery will be working on? A plug-in is likely the way to go, but representative mark-up might suggest another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part1) will guide you down the path you seek.  It is focused on sorting tabular data in html tables, but you can easily re-purpose the examples to work with a group of divs or list elements, or whatever.

Some of the guidance teaches raw JavaScript techniques, with jQuery peppered in for support, so it's a good guide.  For example, it teaches you how to use JavaScript's build in `sort()` method.  Want to sort alphabetically?  Here's a modified snippet from that guide:

```
var parent_of_divs = $('#parent-of-divs'), rows;
rows = parent_of_divs.children('div').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA, keyB;
    keyA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    keyB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    parent_of_divs.append(row);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery) about sorting li items. With little changes it can also be applied in your case. Among others, the [TinySort](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort) plug-in is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

There's an ok example here:

[Example](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)

I found it to be pretty good.  Also, it's a light weight plugin (if you don't want to implement your own).  To me, the code was pretty clear even though I am new to the language.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look into using jquery template lib. you can create a template, and then pass a data object to the template to render. when you want to change the sort order, you would be able to change the data object, and then "update()" your template.