# jQuery and Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Trying to get some custom sorting going on and haven't been able to get it.

This is close to what my table structure looks like..

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> data </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li> 20 </li>
          <ul>
            <li> something </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to sort on the number that sits in that first list element.

Have tried:

```
$("table").tablesorter({ 
    textExtraction: function(node) { 
    return node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; 
}
```

Comment: Tablesorter sorts tables, not unordered lists. To sort a list, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery/1134983#1134983

Comment: My post got butchered by the system here.. the lists sit in the TDs of my table.

Comment: textExtraction: { 7: function(node) { return node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; }. Like it mentions in the examples.

Comment: What exactly do  you mean about the TDs? Please edit  your question to show the real code. If you mean that the `ul` is inside a `td` tablesorter will not work for you - it expects each `td` to have *one* value.

Comment: Dan, the custom textExtraction methods imply otherwise. It clearly shows dom traversal inside TD elements, bypassing markup and sorting on the value returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, now that I understand what you are trying to do... try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/SZd9r/)):

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node) {
        return parseInt( $.trim( $(node).find('li:first').text() ), 10);
    }
});
```

---

Update: Oops I see, it wasn't sorting numerically. Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/SZd9r/22/)):

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    textExtraction: {
        1: function(node) {
            return parseInt( $.trim( $(node).find('li:first').text() ), 10);
        }
    },
    headers: {
        1: { sorter:'digit' }
    }
});
```

Comment: Fudgey, thanks. I've tried something similar to this. Why does adding a column break it?

Comment: How is it broken? The demo you included above seems to work to me.

Comment: Thanks fudgey -- tried several similar renditions prior to asking, but none seemed to work. Had to have been some hiccups in my JS syntax.

Comment: I ended up making a blog post (http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html) about Tablesorter functions that seem to be missing in the docs... I had to dig a bit to figure out what some of them did.