# Simple jquery script not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari

This script works in firefox, IE, and chrome, but not safari. Any ideas?

The really strange thing is that when I put an `alert()` at the end of the `.get()` callback, it executes (even in safari).  So the code isn't crashing, it's just not modifying the DOM.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title for this webpage</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!- CSS styling -------------------------------------------------------------->
<style type="text/css"/>
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;

    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;

    background-color:#fff;
}

#mainBox{
    width:700px;
    margin:30px;
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#mainHeader, #mainFooter, #mainContent{
    margin: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 2px dashed #ddd;
    text-align:center;
}

.shuffleMe{
    margin: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    text-align:left;
}
</style>

<!- Jquery/javascript -------------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
//Code modified from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
  var my_list = $('.shuffleMe').get();
    my_list.sort(function(){return( Math.random() >.5 );});
    $.each(my_list, function(index, item) { $('#mainContent').append(item); });
});
</script>

</head>

<!- HTML body content -------------------------------------------------------->
<body>
<div id="mainBox">
    <div id="mainHeader"> --- HEADER --- </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div class="shuffleMe">AAA</div>
        <div class="shuffleMe">BBB</div>
        <div class="shuffleMe">CCC</div>
        <div class="shuffleMe">DDD</div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainFooter"> --- FOOTER --- </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried with another version of jQuery to see if it is a bug within the version?. also, i've seen a lot of reported problems about Math.random() on safari, maybe there's the problem

Comment: It's modifying the DOM, but the sort order is not changing. If you adjust the HTML of each item in your `$.each()` statement, you'll see that it's getting updated. I'm trying to figure out why the `sort()` method isn't working.

Comment: hm.  Good suggestions.  I've just tried a couple different versions of jquery--no change. Also, I plugged in the line: alert(Math.random());  Each reload gives me a different random-looking number, so I don't think that's the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with your sort function. The sort function should return -1 (less), 0 (equals), or 1 (more); it shouldn't return a boolean. The fact that it works in other browsers is a fluke in this case I think.

```
my_list.sort(function(){return( Math.random() - .5 );});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your sorting function. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsKTL/). This code is working:

```
var my_list = $('.shuffleMe').get();
my_list.sort(function(){
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
$.each(my_list, function(index, item) {$('#mainContent').append(item); });
```