# jQuery Sorting a list by span

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

So i have something linke that:

```
<ul id="list">
<li class="item">
<a>
<span class="name> name1 </span>
</a>
<a>
<span class="name> name2 </span>
</a>
<a>
<span class="name> name3 </span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

how can i sort this list by the name alphabeticaly?

kind regards

Comment: > - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Comment: How is the list built? Is it all client-side? Can you do the sorting on the server-side before the list is rendered? Is it a static list?

Comment: @aSeptik: He wants to sort by a class name within a span within an anchor. Your example is good for reference but isn't a solution for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this plugin:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

using a custom comparator, something like this:

```
$('li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).find('.name').text() > $(b).find('.name').text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: People are pretty fast with google lol. I came up with that exact link and was just typing an answer when I realized someone has answered already haha.

Comment: For those wondering before testing, this works exactly as advertised.  js file is available here:  https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/sortElements

Comment: PS It wasn't case insensitive for me however, so for example `Xylophone` would appear before `rlink` in a list, I chained `.toLowerCase()` to both instances of `text()` and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

> - **demo** http://jsbin.com/itudoc/2

```
$(function() {
    var names = elements = [];
    $('.item .name').each(function(i, item) {
        var name = $.trim($(this).text()) + '_' + i;
        names[i] = name;
        elements[name] = $(this).parent().remove().clone();
    });
    $.each(names.sort(),function(i, item) {
        $('.item').append(elements[item]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, you don't even need a plugin. This code worked for me to sort a list of links:

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){
    return $(a).find('a').text().toLowerCase() > $(b).find('a').text().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
};

$('#thelist li').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('#thelist');
```

No need for span tags with this method.

(the basic idea isn't my own, I copied it from somewhere, but don't remember where from.)