# Sort an html list with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-lists

I have a set of three list items that I would like to automatically display from high to low on page load. Ideally using jquery or javascript.

```
<ul class="list">
<li id="alpha">32</li>
<li id="beta">170</li>
<li id="delta">28</li>
</ul>
```

Each list item needs its own ID because they each have individual background images. The numbers must text nodes so that a user can edit them.

Comment: see here
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1134976/771300

Comment: @maerics I tried originaly to build it up from scratch with an array
`function listSort(a, B)
{
return a - b;
}
var n = ["10", "775", "40", "1125","1", "8"];
document.write(n.sort(listSort));`

I got as far as rearranging the list in order but couldnt figure it to work with different list IDs.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will probably be the fastest way to do it, since it doesn't use jQuery:

```
function sortList(ul){
    var new_ul = ul.cloneNode(false);

    // Add all lis to an array
    var lis = [];
    for(var i = ul.childNodes.length; i--;){
        if(ul.childNodes[i].nodeName === 'LI')
            lis.push(ul.childNodes[i]);
    }

    // Sort the lis in descending order
    lis.sort(function(a, b){
       return parseInt(b.childNodes[0].data , 10) - 
              parseInt(a.childNodes[0].data , 10);
    });

    // Add them into the ul in order
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
        new_ul.appendChild(lis[i]);
    ul.parentNode.replaceChild(new_ul, ul);
}
```

Call the function like:

```
sortList(document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0]);
```

You can sort other lists the same way, and if you have other elements on the same page with the list class you should give your ul an id and pass it in using that instead.

[**Example JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/x92hn/2/)

**Edit**

Since you mentioned that you want it to happen on pageLoad, I'm assuming you want it to happen ASAP after the ul is in the DOM which means you should add the function `sortList` to  the head of your page and use it immediately after your list like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sortList(ul){
            var new_ul = ul.cloneNode(false);
            var lis = [];
            for(var i = ul.childNodes.length; i--;){
                if(ul.childNodes[i].nodeName === 'LI')
                    lis.push(ul.childNodes[i]);
            }
            lis.sort(function(a, b){
               return parseInt(b.childNodes[0].data , 10) - parseInt(a.childNodes[0].data , 10);
            });
            for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
                new_ul.appendChild(lis[i]);
            ul.parentNode.replaceChild(new_ul, ul);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <ul class="list">
        <li id="alpha">32</li>
        <li id="beta">170</li>
        <li id="delta">28</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        !function(){
            var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
            sortList( uls[uls.length - 1] );
        }();
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: That's beautiful - works a charm. Now to try and disect what you wrote..!

Comment: Note: this won't work in versions of IE before IE9 without more code because `getElementsByClassName()` doesn't exist in older versions of IE.

Comment: @danssker - Why you would pick the more complicated native javascript version over the simpler jQuery version if you're already using jQuery?  Can you really see a performance difference on an operation like this?  My mantra in this regard is: go with simplicity first and only add complexity if you absolutely need it.

Comment: Why clone the `UL` node?  You can just reinsert the sorted `LI` nodes to the original `UL` node.

Comment: @jfriend00 You mean versions before IE 7, not IE 9... Also the sortList function works in IE 6, just need to call it differently like I said with using an id.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is much faster to clone the node, because the browser doesn't need to rerender after every appendChild. The difference will be in the seconds range if the ul contains thousands of lis.

Comment: @jfriend00 I meant reflow not rerender

Comment: I think you're mistaken.  According to both [this compatibility page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) and [this test page](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hwd8D/) run in IE8, `document.getElementsByClassName()` does not exist in IE8.  This is one of the advantages of using jQuery - you don't have to do selector-type things differently in different browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00 Huh... I suppose you're right about `getElementsByclassName`, still it's better to just use an id, and like I said my sortList function is cross browser :) It's easy to write your own getElementsByClassName for browsers which do not support it, and considering the OP wants this to execute immediately I think it's a good idea to use the fastest code possible.

Comment: @jfriend00 I said if i was using jquery I would have gone with jquery. For exactly the same reason you mentioned, why complicate things by preloading the jquery library when I only needed it for this one thing.

Comment: @danssker - you did tag your question with jQuery.  I'm not sure why you did that if you don't want any jQuery solutions.

Comment: @jfriend00 true, i did that. my apologies. i guess i'd did expect so many comprehensive replies. I'm a bit overwhelmed!

Comment: @danssker I'm glad you tagged it with `jquery`, although this solution seems neat, since I'm using jQuery, I prefer the solution with it.

Comment: `for(var i = ul.childNodes.length; i--;)` is equivalent to `for(var i = ul.childNodes.length - 1; i>=0; i--)`. Seems like it's a shortcut that takes advantage of [the optional nature of the for statements's final-expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) by decrementing within the conditional and leaving the final-expression blank. I had never seen this before so I had to take some time to puzzle this out.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
var ul = $(".list:first");
var arr = $.makeArray(ul.children("li"));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = +$(a).text();
    var textB = +$(b).text();

    if (textA < textB) return -1;
    if (textA > textB) return 1;

    return 0;
});

ul.empty();

$.each(arr, function() {
    ul.append(this);
});
```

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/B7hdx/1

Comment: Have you fully tested your live example? It displayed "170 28 32"

Comment: Nice... if my site was already using jquery I would have used this.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [this small jQuery plugin](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/). Which would make your sort nothing more than:

```
$('.list>li').tsort({attr:'id'});
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use this lightweight jquery plugin [List.js](http://listjs.com/) cause

1. it's lightweight [only 3K script]
2. easy to implement in your existing HTML table using class
3. searchable, sortable and filterable

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-list">
    <ul class="list">
       <li>
           <h3 class="name">Luke</h3>
       </li>
       <li>
           <h3 class="name">John</h3>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
};
var myList = new List('my-list', options);
```

Answer (score 5):

This code will sort that list assuming there is only one `.list` item:

```
function sortList(selector) {
    var parent$ = $(selector);
    parent$.find("li").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
        return(Number(a.innerHTML) - Number(b.innerHTML));
    }).each(function(index, el) {
        parent$.append(el);
    });
}

sortList(".list");
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FjuMB/

To explain how it works:

1. It gets the .list parent object.
2. It finds all the `<li>` child objects.
3. It removes all the `<li>` child objects from the DOM, but preserves their data
4. It sorts the li objects using a custom sort function
5. The custom sort function gets the HTML in the li tag and converts it to a number
6. Then, traversing the array in the newly sorted order, each li tag is appended back onto the original parent.

The result is that they are displayed in sorted order.

**Edit:**

This improved version will even sort multiple list objects at once:

```
function sortList(selector) {
    $(selector).find("li").sort(function(a, b) {
        return(Number(a.innerHTML) - Number(b.innerHTML));
    }).each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).parent().append(el);
    });
}

sortList(".list");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RsLwX/

Answer (score 3):

**Non jquery version (vanilla javascript)**

Benefits: the list is sorted in place, which doesn't destroy the LI's nor remove any events that may be associated with them. It just shuffles things around

Added an id to the UL:

```
<ul id="myList" class="list">
    <li id="alpha">32</li>
    <li id="beta">170</li>
    <li id="delta">28</li>
</ul>
```

and the vanilla javascript (no jquery)

```
// Grab a reference to the UL
var container = document.getElementById("myList");

// Gather all the LI's from the container
var contents = container.querySelectorAll("li");

// The querySelector doesn't return a traditional array
// that we can sort, so we'll need to convert the contents 
// to a normal array.
var list = [];
for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++){
    list.push(contents[i]);
}

// Sort based on innerHTML (sorts "in place")
list.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = parseInt(a.innerHTML);
    var bb = parseInt(b.innerHTML);
    return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});

// We'll reverse the array because our shuffle runs backwards
list.reverse();

// Shuffle the order based on the order of our list array.
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    console.log(list[i].innerHTML);
    container.insertBefore(list[i], container.firstChild);
}
```

And the fiddle proof: https://jsfiddle.net/L27gpnh6/1/

Comment: Bob thanks, the best solution I've found thus far. You can also use data attributes `parseInt(a.getAttribute(attr))`

Comment: Thanks,
Here is a solution for sorting alphabetically:
`list.sort(function(a, b){`
   `var aa = a.innerHTML;`
    `var bb = b.innerHTML;`
   `return aa.localeCompare(bb);`
`});`

Answer (score 1):

One method could be to [sort an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (well, a jQuery object) of the `li` elements and replace the contents (using the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method) of the `ul` with the sorted array of elements:

```
$(".list").html($(".list li").sort(function(a, b) {
     return parseInt($(b).text(), 10) - parseInt($(a).text(), 10);    
}));
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XGPt9/2/).

Comment: thanks, looks nice but.. not sure the sort array is working properly here? looks like its sorting by first digit and not by the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
var mylist = $('ul');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Check the article here:
http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

**Edit:** There is a very cool jquery plugin that does that : http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:

```
var $parent = $(".list");

$(".list li").sort(function (a, b) {
    return window.parseInt($(a).text(), 10) - window.parseInt($(b).text(), 10);
}).remove().each(function () {
    $parent.append($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery for help:

```
var sortFunction = function(a, b) {
    return (+($(b).text())) - (+($(a).text()));
}
var lis = $('ul.list li');
lis = Array.prototype.sort.call(lis, sortFunction);

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    $('ul.list').append(lis[i]);
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrim/cCAFD/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Sort jQuery collection as usual array and then append each element back in correct order.

```
$(".list li").sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(b).text(), 10) - parseInt($(a).text(), 10);    
}).appendTo('.list');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zMmWj/