# How to sort <ul> list?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort an html list with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837191/sort-an-html-list-with-javascript)

I have an :

```
<ul>
<li>Anytime</li>
<li>Cash is good</li>
<li>Do it now!</li>
</ul>
```

I constantly add new articles. I want them to be in an alphabetical order without having re-arrange them manually.
I have written my site in pure HTML and CSS (I don't get information from a database).

How do I solve this? Do I need Java-script?

Comment: No, but you need JavaScript.

Comment: At the moment this can't be done using pure CSS/HTML.

Comment: Java? Heavens no. JavaScript? If you want. How are you adding the articles in the first place?

Comment: I meant java-script -sorry! Would it be possible to do with ease using jQuery?

Comment: [Alphabetize with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)

Comment: check this thread : [Sorting A Un-Ordered List (UL) Using JavaScript](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1947)

Answer (score 5):

#### Based on an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837191/sort-an-html-list-with-javascript), check this out:

```
var ul = $("ul");
var arr = $.makeArray(ul.children("li"));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = +$(a).text();
    var textB = +$(b).text();

    if (textA < textB) return -1;
    if (textA > textB) return 1;

    return 0;
});

ul.empty();

$.each(arr, function() {
    ul.append(this);
});
```

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Anytime</li>
    <li>Cash is good</li>
    <li>Do it now!</li>
</ul>
```