# Sort the order of a UL generated by a wordpress plugin using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html-lists

I have some drop-down menus from a plugin that do not display their contents in alphabetical or an ascending/descending order.

The lists look like this in the inspector:

```
<ul class="options">
    <li class = "opt">
        <span><i></i></span>
        <label> BAC </label>
    </li>
    <li class = "opt">
        <span><i></i></span>
        <label> ACD </label>
    </li>
    <li class = "opt">
        <span><i></i></span>
        <label> FBC </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to sort these li's by the contents of the label.

The order of the list is currently whatever was entered into a spreadsheet last is at the top.

I have attempted some solutions found here including this one [Sort an html list with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837191/sort-an-html-list-with-javascript)

However, the order of my drop down remains the same.

This is my first time asking a question, let me know if I left out anything crucial. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked wether the plugin gave functionality for sorting or not?

Comment: After trying the answer below without success I kept looking and the plugin is using another plugin called sumoselect that does not allow you to sort alphabetically. I am still hoping to find a workaround but I am still trying to figure out how sumo select works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a jQuery collection and append that collection to parent

```js
$('ul.options').append(function() {
  return $(this).children().sort(function(a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).find('label').text().trim(),
        bText = $(b).find('label').text().trim();
    return aText.localeCompare(bText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="options">
  <li class="opt">
    <span><i></i></span>
    <label> BAC </label>
  </li>
  <li class="opt">
    <span><i></i></span>
    <label> ACD </label>
  </li>
  <li class="opt">
    <span><i></i></span>
    <label> FBC </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```