# Sorting Jquery returned HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

**Technology:** Asp.net with jQuery.

*Hi geeks,*

**Overview:**
I'm a jQuery noob , I have been working on this Jquery script to enable OnEnter keypress move to the next input element (textarea,select,input ,etc) ,I have tried several solutions of my own ,even tried solutions available online ,but every solution have some weakness or limitation ,well I have finally got a solution which is good enough for me ,but it still has some problems.

**Problem:**
I have queried all the elements having attribute [tabindex], now jquery returns all the elements in DOM as they are present in their hierarchy ,but I want elements sorted according to their tabindex.

**1)** So elements needs to be sorted so that I could move to next element based on the tabindex but not on the basis of their hierarchy.
**2)** What if any element is set to readonly="readonly" or disabled = "disabled" ,that element should not get focus at all ?

I dont want to mess up the question by putting Jquery and HTML code ,so I have created [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPB9s/12/)

Let me know how to tackle this.
**P.S:** Let me know I you guys need more info.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: shamelessly stolen the idea of @Kolink

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
     var arr=$(":input[tabindex]:not('[disabled=disabled],[readonly=readonly]')");//this will give you the input elements that are not disabled or readonly

     //as Kolink mentioned in his answer use the .sort function of javascript array to sort the array according to the tab index 
     var newArr=arr.sort(function(a,b){   
     return a[1]-b[1];
     });
     console.log(newArr);
     $(newArr[0]).select().focus(); // focus the element with tabindex=1
     var $currentFocus=0;//set the currentFocus pointer to the first element of the sorted array
     var $arrLen = newArr.length;
 $(':input').live("keydown", function (e) {        DO NOT USE .live as it is deprecated but i will go with it for the time being see the link to .delegate at the end of the answer                  
  if (e.which == 13) //Enter key
   {
     e.preventDefault();     
     if($currentFocus<$arrLen){     
        $(newArr[$currentFocus+1]).focus();     
        $currentFocus++;     //increment the pointer    
     }else {
        console.log("submit form");
        alert("submit form");
     }
   }
 }); //end of keydown function

});​
```

[**.sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[**.delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPB9s/14/)

Comment: @Jhon You must up vote Kolink ,he deserves it :),I just verifying your fiddle

Comment: ':input[tabindex]' I only want to select elements having tabindex attribute

Comment: @Jhon .delegate is the  update for .live ,Thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

The way I sort any array of nodes is simple.

First, loop through the NodeList and build an array. Each array element is `[element, thing to sort by]`. In this case, `[element, element.tabIndex]`.

Then, use `sort` with a callback:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a[1]-b[1];});
```

This will sort by the second element of each array, which is the thing to sort by.

Optionally, use `map` to turn each array element into just its first element (`arr.map(function(a) {return a[0];});`)

You now have your sorted array of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the input,but noobs need some more explanation :)