# Sorting select options with jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I fund a very nice sorting function here
[How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)
works almost perfect except that it looks like sorts by first charachter only , for example 
if you have something like

```
0-5000
5001-10000
10001-15000
15001-20000
```

the order will look like

```
0-5000
10001-15000
15001-20000
5001-10000
```

instead

```
0-5000
5001-10000
10001-15000
15001-20000
```

I redid the function for every select in the form

```
var mylist = $('#myformid select');

$(mylist).each(function (sorter, elm) { 
  var listitems = $(this).children('option.myoptionclass').get();
   listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
      var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
      return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
   })
     $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { 
          $(this).parent().append(itm); 
      });

});
```

here is live example

http://jsfiddle.net/sQsZQ/6/

any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I editted your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CBD33/2/
I'm using `parseInt` so the comparison looks like this now:

```
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
  var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
  var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
  compA = (parseInt(compA,10) || compA)
  compB = (parseInt(compB,10) || compB)              


  return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
```

If the first character of the string value given to `parseInt` is a numeral, it will parse everything up to the first non-digit character. If the first character isn't a numeral, it'll return NaN. My use of `||` there is rather lazy, but I'm sure you can come up with a better condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to numbers before you sort like this

```
   var compA = parseInt($(a).text().split('-')[0]);
   var compB = parseInt($(b).text().split('-')[0]);
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/sQsZQ/8/

Comment: Your solution seems to work because the input was already sorted, but `'somestring'.split[0]` returns undefined.

Comment: @Daveo thnx for submitting but did you notice that the second select is not sorting anymore because it does not have -

Comment: @Benn No I never even noticed the 2nd select box. In that case you shoud use KGZM answer