# Insert new list sorted in alphabetical order, javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have lists, already sorted alphabetically as below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Apple</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Banana</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Grapes</a></li>
<ul>
```

So i wanted to add new list which has the value of `Chico` so it should be inserted between `Banana` and `Grapes`...like it will fade in. So i have a form or an input field to add a new list of fruits...

Is there any way to do that using jquery or javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: iterate over every element and when you find the correct position to insert, you can use `.insertBefore`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){  
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
}

$("#insert").on('click', function() {
    var newLi = $("<li><a href='#'>"+$("#fruit").val()+"</a></li>").hide();
    $('li', 'ul').add(newLi.fadeIn(800)).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('ul');
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cJL6L/2/)

Answer (score 2):

See this [working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eJSe6/)!

This function adds the new list item to the provided list.
After adding the new item, it will sort all items by their contents.

```
function addNewListItem($list, $ele) {

    // append new element
    $list.append($ele);

    // get all elements
    var listItems = $list.children('li').get();

    // sort elements by contents
    listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
       return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
    });
    $.each(listItems, function(idx, itm) { $list.append(itm); });
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
//Creating a new item
var $newLI = $('<li/>').append($('<a/>', {"href":'#',"title":''}).html('Chico'));

// adding and sorting
addNewListItem($('ul'), $newLI);
```

---

Original sort function is credit to [Dan @ onemoretake](http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/), via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134983/352449) stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

***CSS***

```
.hide {
   display: none
}
```

***jQuery***

```
function addListElement(el) {
    var lis = $('ul li').add(el).sort(function(a, b) {
        return $('a', a).text() > $('a', b).text();
    });

    $('ul').html(lis).find('.hide').fadeIn(3000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hide')
    });
}

addListElement('<li class="hide"><a href="#">Chico</a></li>');
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/610/)**