# Sorting an UL Class childs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I am VERY new to JavaScript.  I have looked at several previously answered questions along this line.  My HTML is roughly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.skills{
list-style:none;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 200px;
}
.skills li{
width: 200px;
float: left;
padding: 0;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Skills</h2>
<ul class="skills">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
</ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried to use:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function sortLi()
    {
      var skills = [getElementsbyTagName("li")];
      skills.sort();
          var x=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
              x.innerHTML=skills;
     }
  </script>
```

and by swapping .getElementsbyTagName with .getElementsbyClass("skills") to no avail.  I know that I am doing something wrong but just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I guess I should have said I am looking to alphabetically sort.

Comment: you should use `getElementById('skills')` to get the element and of course set the `ul` element to have the id of skills

Comment: var x=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

Comment: Probably this answer can be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1135099/189431 . Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/De8Ku/

Comment: ok I made your corrections McMastermind and also corrected my typos (formatting) and still have no luck :(

Comment: Koen, I did see that one.  I just do not want it with a button, on load is perfect for my needs.  I know that I am all around this thing but I cannot land the answer.

Comment: Anything called getElements in plural returns a collection and needs [0] to get at the first item. Also add `document.` to your getElements...

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution [(here is a link at jsfiddle.)](http://jsfiddle.net/qLRDF/)

```
var mylist = $('.skills');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
    mylist.append(itm);
});​
```

This uses jQuery and is almost wholly lifted from another [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery) answer.

Basically you have some syntax errors, you don't call your code, etc. Take a look at how the working solution I've linked to at jsfiddle functions and see if that helps.