# How to sort DOM elements while selecting in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have the following DIVs on my page:

```
<div id="pi_div3">
  Div 3
</div>
<div id="pi_div2">
  Div 2
</div>
<div id="pi_div1">
  Div 1
</div>
<div id="pi_div6">
  Div 6
</div>
<div id="pi_div5">
  Div 5
</div>
<div id="pi_div4">
  Div 4
</div>
```

I am trying to select the Divs using the jQuery code `$("div[id*=pi_div]")`.

I need the divs to be sorted based on their IDs when I do an each() on the selector. When I loop through the DIVs, the order should be: PI_DIV1, PI_DIV2, PI_DIV3, PI_DIV4, PI_DIV5, PI_DIV6. How can I do that in jQuery?

Comment: Sort *after*, not *during*. `jQuery(..)` returns an "array like" object and an there is `Array.sort` that can take a custom compare function.

Comment: Here is a solved similar question:

[how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can call [.sort()](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.html) before calling [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$("div[id*=pi_div]").sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.id < b.id) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}).each(function() { console.log($(this).attr("id"));});
```

*EDIT: I was wondering why the other answers are removing the `pi_div` part of the id and I get it. If you compare based on the "strings" `pi_div10` will come before `pi_div2`.*

Comment: @HRK : You should accept someone else's answer, mine work just because your number of elements is limited. I let it to explain why it wouldn't work in general

Comment: This function is flawed. It compares string values, which will not create the correct result.

Comment: @Tomalak > It is written clearly in the answer and I asked HRK to accept another one. I wanted to leave it to avoid someone making the same mistake.

Comment: Your comment was not visible to me before I wrote mine. :)

Comment: @Tomalak > no but the EDIT in the answer was there before my answer was accepted. I can't delete it now that it is accepted, should i flag it ?

Comment: I would wait until the OP comes online again. He's not seen your comment yet. Accepted answers cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 8):

If you also want to sort them visibly on the page

```
$('div[id^="pi_div"]').sort(function (a, b) {
    var re = /[^\d]/g;
    return ~~a.id.replace(re, '') > ~~b.id.replace(re, '');
})
.appendTo("#container");
```

Note the `~~` which converts the values into integers, otherwise they would be compared as strings.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Xjc2T/

Comment: I would use `parseInt` or just convert them into numbers using '+'. It's a little more obvious.

Comment: @Blazemonger Well, you are right, it would be same thing. However, `~~` also handles `undefined` and `Infinity`, so I tend to use that.

Comment: Thanks for adding `.appendTo('#container')` that updates elements sort order in the DOM three.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("div[id^=pi_div]").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.id.replace('pi_div', '') > b.id.replace('pi_div', '');
}).foo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KrX7t/

Comment: Worth noting that jQuery's `.sort()` method is intended for internal use and is undocumented on purpose.

Comment: Strictly speaking, no, it's not an array, or it wouldn't need to have a `toArray()` method. But it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck.

Comment: @Blazemonger the .sort method is just inherited from the native Array.prototype.sort method. It's not jQuery's, it is intended for external use, and it's undocumented because it's not part of jquery.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Array.sort method. http://jsfiddle.net/LJWrg/

```
var divArr = $("div[id*=pi_div]");
function cleanId(id) {
    return parseInt(id.replace("pi_div",""),10);
}
Array.prototype.sort.call(divArr,function(a,b) {
    return cleanId(a.id) > cleanId(b.id);
});
divArr.each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

jQuery does come with this method internally defined, so you can shorten it to this (however it uses undocumented methods) http://jsfiddle.net/LJWrg/1/:

```
var divArr = $("div[id*=pi_div]");
function cleanId(id) {
    return parseInt(id.replace("pi_div",""),10);
}
divArr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return cleanId(a.id) > cleanId(b.id);
});
divArr.each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```