# jQuery Tablesorter - initial sort rows from array

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

i'm trying to inital sort a table by it's row-numbers from an array/variable like

```
$list: row0=id2;row1=id0;row2=id1...

<table>
<tr id="0">...</tr>
<tr id="1">...</tr>
<tr id="2">...</tr>
</table>
```

How can i handle with tablesorter that the rows will be sorted like in $list?

thanks for any tipp or workaround :)

Comment: Use your list with sortlist param http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html

Comment: thanks :) ... i've tried but i can't get the array used for sort :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of: [How to sort DOM elements while selecting in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878638/how-to-sort-dom-elements-while-selecting-in-jquery)

```js
$('#myt tr').sort(function(a, b) {
  if (parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id)) return 1;
  else return -1;
}).each(function() {
  $('#myt').append($(this));
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myt'>
  <tr id="8">
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="21">
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that's my array

Array (1)
0 => "0=4;1=0;2=1;3=2;4=3"

what i need is the following issue: 

0=4; means id4 will become row 0

Comment: the array is build with var ordered_items = $.tableDnD.serialize('id');

Answer (score -1):

maybe not what was originally intended but it's a workaround :)

```
var sortTable = [1,5,2,3,4];
$.each(sortTable, function(){
   $("table#productList").append($("#" + this));
 })
```

thanks for the responses and help!!