# Universal jQuery sort solution for all tables in document

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to implement a universal jQuery sort solution for my tables so that when the user clicks on thead element then it will sort the column in alphabetical or numerical order. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/uJmJ7/

```
<table class="ui-widget" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead class="ui-widget-header">
        <tr>
            <th>Module Code</th>
            <th>Module Name</th>
            <th>Module Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="ui-widget-content">
        <tr>
            <tr class="moduleList">
                <td class="moduleList_id">SB005</td>
                <td class="moduleList_name">Accounting</td>
                <td class="moduleList_grade">79</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="moduleList">
                <td class="moduleList_id">SA572</td>
                <td class="moduleList_name">Statistics</td>
                <td class="moduleList_grade">45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="moduleList">
                <td class="moduleList_id">SA570</td>
                <td class="moduleList_name">Methods for Business</td>
                <td class="moduleList_grade">56</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="moduleList">
                <td class="moduleList_id">SA526</td>
                <td class="moduleList_name">Finance</td>
                <td class="moduleList_grade">89</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="moduleList">
                <td class="moduleList_id">SA512</td>
                <td class="moduleList_name">Leisure</td>
                <td class="moduleList_grade">66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="moduleList">
                <td class="moduleList_id">SA510</td>
                <td class="moduleList_name">Environment</td>
                <td class="moduleList_grade">30</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Find a plugin, there must be hundreds that does this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Comment: Agreed.  DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/) does it very nicely, and has a ton more features to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into either a plugin or something like KendoUI that has this feature and more....

[KendoUI](http://demos.kendoui.com/)

[DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/)