# JqPlot(JQuery) sort legend-labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqplot, jquery-ui-sortable

I have got a question:

Is it possible to sort labels of my legend at Jqplot?

```
legend: {
         show: true,
         placement: 'outsideGrid'
},
```

Comment: I think labels are sorted according to their appearance order or index if you give jqplot an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this to sort the rows in the legend (inspired by [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)):

```
var rows = $('#chart .jqplot-table-legend tr').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).children().last().text().localeCompare($(b).children().last().text());
});

$.each(rows, function(index, item) {
    $('#chart .jqplot-table-legend tbody').append(item);
});
```

This works best for the standard legend renderer - it will also work for the `EnhancedLegendRenderer`, but toggling a series visible/invisible will actually show or hide the series that corresponded to the label that was there prior to being sorted.