# The sort () function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Surely the problem is not in function, but as the following code shows, it is necessary that you click two times to sort it in descending ~ growing. How can I fix this?

[Here is a jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3T5kN/4/)

I believe that the error in this :

```
function lxp(a, b){
    var adate = new Date($(a).attr("data-date"));
    var bdate = new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
    if(tipo == 'acrescente'){
        return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
    }else if(tipo == 'decrescente'){
        return adate > bdate ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. You really should take the time to proofread your question before you post it.

Comment: Yes, I'm used to traditional forums and ended up doing this, I'm sorry.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `sort()` method. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery) is similar to yours, however.

Comment: No. I'm doing it with date and not words, and the problem is specific to what I'm using, not generalized "how-to" ...

Comment: @Blazemonger, jQuery *does* have a `sort` method, but it's undocumented and equivalent to `Array.prototype.sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the most straight forward approach to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/3T5kN/11/

```
$(function(){
    var tllp = 15;
    $('#blocoSite li').each(function(i, lep){
        $(lep).css({ top : tllp });
        tllp += 15;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    var tipo = "decrescente";
    $('#ordeData').click(function() { 
        tipo = tipo == "acrescente" ? "decrescente" : "acrescente"
        var nposY = 0;

        function lxp(a, b){
            var adate = new Date($(a).attr("data-date"));
            var bdate = new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));

            if(tipo == 'acrescente'){
                return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
            }else if(tipo == 'decrescente'){
                return adate < bdate ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }

        $("#blocoSite li").sort(lxp).each(function(i, el){
            nposY = i * 15;

            $(this).animate({
                left: 200,
                top :  nposY
            }, 800);
        });

    })
})
```

With accompanying HTML

```
<ul id="blocoSite">
    <li data-date="2010-05-12">2010</li>
    <li data-date="2012-05-12">2012</li>
    <li data-date="2015-05-12">2015</li>
    <li data-date="2008-05-12">2008</li>
    <li data-date="2009-05-12">2009</li>
    <li data-date="2010-05-12">2010</li>
</ul>
<button id="ordeData">CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a 0 to the months smaller than 10 like `<li data-date="2010-05-12">`instead of `<li data-date="2010-5-12">`

I did that in your fiddle a the list get sorted at the first click

EDIT: updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3T5kN/8/)

I get this. It's no ok?

- 2015
- 2012
- 2010
- 2010
- 2009
- 2008

Comment: Tested and did not work ...

Comment: The problem is other clicks to add he and descending..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "Invalid date" errors from `adate` and `bdate`, so I turned your date-strings into numbers (using `parseInt`) and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/3T5kN/7/

Comment: works on the first click, then he'll settling other ways...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the javascriptcode with:

```
$(function(){
    var tllp = 15;
    $('#blocoSite li').each(function(i, lep){
        $(lep).css({ top : tllp });
        tllp += 15;
    });
});

function orderDate(tipo){
    $('#ordered').remove();
    var nposX = 0;
    var nposY = 0;

    if(tipo == 'acrescente'){
        $("#ordeData").attr({'onclick' : 'orderDate("decrescente");'});
    }else if(tipo == 'decrescente'){
        $("#ordeData").attr({'onclick' : 'orderDate("acrescente");'});
    }


    function lxp(a, b){
        var adate = new Date($(a).attr("data-date"));
        var bdate = new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
        if(tipo == 'acrescente'){
            return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
        }else if(tipo == 'decrescente'){
            return adate < bdate ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    var order="";
    nposY = 0;
    $("#blocoSite li").sort(lxp).each(function(i, el){
        order += el.outerHTML+"\n";
        nposY += 15;

        $(this).animate({
            left: 200,
            top :  nposY
        }, 800);
    });
    $('#ordered').html(order);
}
```

This way, you will put the list-items in the sorted order, rather than one based on the old position (in addition to the sort) of the item.