# javascript sorting jquery

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I am doing i a lot of sorting and currently doing it like this:

```
function sortby(a, b, prop) {
    if (a[prop].toLowerCase() > b[prop].toLowerCase())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1
}
```

Used like this:

```
someArray.sort(function (a, b) { return sortby(a, b, 'propertyname') });
```

But I suspect it is possible to do something more clever with apply or binding, like

```
someArray.sort(sortby.bind(a,b,'propertyname'))?
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134983/1075211

Comment: Rather than the `>` comparison you're doing, you might as well use the built in `localecompare` and do `return a[prop].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[prop].toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible. `apply` returns the result of a function, so it's not applicable here, however, `bind` fits.

You may wish to read the [MDN docs for Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind).

Since bind works in order, if you alter the order of your parameters this is nice and elegant. Let's change the signature of `sortby` to: `function sortby(prop, a, b) {`. Now we can easily tell bind to fix the first parameter:

```
someArray.sort(sortby.bind(undefined, 'propertyname'));
```

Note the `undefined`. The first parameter to `bind` (as per the docs) is a new `this` reference. Since we don't use it, we'll pass `undefined` to say that we don't want to change the context. The next parameter tells bind to create a function which passes a value of 'propertyname' as the first argument to `sortby`. This gives us a *partial function application*; returning a function which takes two parameters, calling `sortby` with the first value that we've already given it, then the two parameters. This function is passed to `sort`, calling it as it needs.

Manually interpreting the call to bind, it gives you something like this:

```
someArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    sortby.apply(this, 'propertyname', a, b);
});
```

Comment: Excellent - both solution and explanation!