# Sorting DOM elements doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to sort an array of list elements in IE8 like this:

```
function comparator(params) {
    var keepSelectedOnTop = params.keepSelectedOnTop;

    return function (a, b) {    // a, b are DOM objects
        a = $(a);  // wrap with jQuery
        b = $(b);

        if (keepSelectedOnTop) {
            if (a.is(".selected") && !b.is(".selected")) {
                return -1;
            } else if (!a.is(".selected") && b.is(".selected")) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return a.text().localeCompare(b.text());
    }
}

// ...

var items = $("ul li").detach().toArray();

items.sort(comparator(params));
```

This works for small lists, but when I have many elements I get an `undefined is null or not an object` error. When I break on the exception with the debugger `b` is `undefined` after the assignment.

Did anyone encounter this before? It works fine in other browsers and it seems perfectly valid JS.

P.S. the jQuery version is 1.7.2

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE8. share the code where you're collecting DOM elements in `a` and `b`

Comment: @badZoke the jQuery version is 1.7.2. The `a` and `b` parameters are populated during the execution of `Array.prototype.sort` which calls the comparator.

Comment: Could you try to debug which values the `b` has before wrapping it (before the assignment)? (You might need to rename the parameters to see it)

Comment: You are sorting a list of jquery objects so a and b are already jquery objects. Don't know if that will help with the problem. and look at: http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery or http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: @Jacob: No. jQuery collections are lists of DOM elements, not of jQuery objects.

Comment: Before assignment `b` holds an object of type `DispHTMLLIElement` and after it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial & error attempts it seems that changing the assignments in the comparator solves the issue, but it doesn't make sense:

```
function comparator(params) {
    var keepSelectedOnTop = params.keepSelectedOnTop;

    return function (aDom, bDom) {
        var a = $(aDom), b = $(bDom);  // Use different vars for the wrappers

        if (keepSelectedOnTop) {
            if (a.is(".selected") && !b.is(".selected")) {
                return -1;
            } else if (!a.is(".selected") && b.is(".selected")) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return a.text().localeCompare(b.text());
    }
}
```

For some reason the above works, but the initial version where I reassigned different values to the parameters doesn't.

Comment: This seems like another IE8 easter egg. Nevertheless the error doesn't reproduce after changing the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Why sort?

```
var items = $("ul li")
items = [].concat(items.filter(".selected").toArray()
                  ,items.filter(":not(.selected)").toArray())
```

Comment: The list items have to be sorted first by their selected state and then by their labels.

Comment: Ah, I missed the localeCompare line. What is the html, so we can test? jsfiddle?