# How to iterate through nested objects with delay

Tags: javascript, callback, timeout, iteration, delay

I cannot figure this out alone and need your help.
I am working with nested backbone objects in a phonegap app and want to save them all. While saving, I want to show a loading animation. When everything is saved I want to continue with the next page/step.
I achieved this already, but the animation is not working, because my saving loops are blocking all UI updates. (I am saving to localStorage, not via ajax.) So I tried to slow saving down by inserting timeouts between saving each item. Now the saving is delayed, but the inteface continues to the next page before everything is really saved. My callbacks seem to be set up incorrectly.

Do you know a pattern for clean nested callbacks?

I have put together [a fiddle that illustrates my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/tsolti/ux7Se/6/).

Can you help me to fix it, so that it creates the alerts in the correct order: `A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, B1, B2, B3, Everything is finished`

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the code if you don't want to check out the fiddle:

```
var forest = {
    "trees": [{
        "id": "tree A",
            "leaves": [{
            "name": "A1"
        }, {
            "name": "A2"
        }, {
            "name": "A3"
        }, {
            "name": "A4"
        }, {
            "name": "A5"
        }, {
            "name": "A6"
        }, {
            "name": "A7"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "tree B",
            "leaves": [{
            "name": "B1"
        }, {
            "name": "B2"
        }, {
            "name": "B3"
        }]
    }]
};

var callback = function () {
    alert("Everything is finished");
};

var workOnTree = function (tree, callback) {
    var leaves = tree.leaves;
    var leafCount = 0;
    var delayedAlert = function () {
        alert(leaves[leafCount].name);
        leafCount += 1;
        if (leafCount < leaves.length) {
            setTimeout(delayedAlert, 1000);
        } else {
            if (callback !== undefined && typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        }
    };
    setTimeout(delayedAlert, 1000);
};

var workOnForest = function (forest, callback) {
    var trees = forest.trees;
    var treeCount = 0;
    var delayedExecution = function () {
        if (treeCount == (trees.length - 1)) {
            // for last tree pass callback
            workOnTree(trees[treeCount], callback);
        } else {
            workOnTree(trees[treeCount]);
        }
        treeCount += 1;
        if (treeCount < trees.length) {
            // this gives a delay between the trees
            setTimeout(delayedExecution, 1000);
        }
    };
    setTimeout(delayedExecution, 1000);
};
workOnForest(forest, callback);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work better if you only triggered setTimeout for the next callback during processing the current one? That way, they are properly serialised.

Comment: still trying to understand what you mean. :-) I have two nested for loops if you look at it closely. for each tree, for each leaf. how would you to the trick?

Comment: If I had only one loop, you were right (if I understood you correctly...). For one loop setTimeout doesn't change the sequentiality (if that's a word :-) )

Comment: my current idea is to pass the callback function to the tree with the most leafs. since the callback should be executed only once and only when all work is done, this might be a better solution that what I have so far. What do you think?

Comment: anybody? does anybody have a better solution for this? my solution is more a workaround. I'd be interested in a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, and I think I do (but I may be wrong) wouldn't you be better off with a Queue model?

You need setTimout() essentially just to run the UI events so you get updates. That doesn't need to be very long, 0ms or 1ms (just in case of optimisation) would be fine.

What I would do is have a single callback function that takes one leaf item from one of your lists, processes it, and then keeps re-scheduling more work with setTimeout() each time if there's still more work to do.

That way, your operations will get processed serially. I don't think you wanted them running in parallel, although it looks like that's what's happening. So your callbacks will be serialised too.

I know you've built a contrived example specifically to demonstrate the problem as simply as possible, but that makes it a little tricky to see what you're trying to do, but do I have that about right?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I stumbled upon queues as well after posting my own anser here and I think it's the way to go. As soon as I manage to implement it with queues I'll mark your answer as the accepted one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use .sort() method and you should add your own parameters this method. These will give you a idea:
[How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: Hi Lightsaber. I don't see how sorting would help me. I actually don't want to sort things, but process collections of objects in a deterministic but delayed manner.

Comment: I see you were mislead by my stupid example.. the numeration is only to show the order of the execution I desire.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with adding the callback to the longest collection. This way the callback occurs after everything was processed.

In the delayed execution function I do this:

```
if (treeCount == maxLeavesTreeIndex) {
    // for last tree pass callback
    workOnTree(trees[treeCount], callback);
}
```

So not the last processed collection gets the callback, but the largest collection.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsolti/ux7Se/7/).

What do you think of this solution?

If you have a better idea, please file an answer.