# How to order div's by a number (with decimals) in the content of this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to order some div's by a number in its content. I used this code:

```
jQuery("#Overzicht > div").sort(function(a, b) {
    var upA = jQuery('.distance-order', a).text().toUpperCase();
    var upB = jQuery('.distance-order', b).text().toUpperCase();
    return upA < upB; }).appendTo('#Overzicht');
```

I found this code at this item:
[How to sort nested divs depending upon content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254461/how-to-sort-nested-divs-depending-upon-content)

But I just have a problem with getting it ordered at number (with decimals). You can find the whole set up over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/84GRA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
jQuery("#Overzicht > div").sort(function(a, b) {
    var upA = parseFloat(jQuery('.distance-order', a).text());
    var upB = parseFloat(jQuery('.distance-order', b).text());
    return upB - upA;
}).appendTo('#Overzicht');
```

This replaces the `toUpperCase` with `parseFloat`, and [returns a proper value from the sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

If you want to sort them in the other direction, simply switch `upA` and `upB`:

```
return upA - upB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `toUpperCase()` on a number which won't do anything. To check for comparison between numbers, you need to parse it first with `parseFloat()`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84GRA/1/)

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work, as the sort function doesn't return the expected results. (easiest to check if you change the `<` to `>`)

Comment: I have not tampered with the sort function. I have just explained why he wasn't getting the expected result. The code which he got might have an issue.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the sort function was part of the problem ;-)

Comment: Ah then that's fine :)