# Sorting using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following codes. 
How can I sort them in DESC order using jQuery? Or is it possible to use CSS to sort? But I prefer jQuery...

```
<div class="bf-attr-block-cont">

<div class="bf-attr-filter bf-attr-2 bf-row">
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2pm.com" name="attribute_value[2][]" id="bf-attr-2-0">
    </span>
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-2">
        <label class="bf-attr-val" for="bf-attr-2-0">2pm.com</label>
    </span>
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-3"><span class="bf-count">4</span></span>
</div>

<div class="bf-attr-filter bf-attr-2 bf-row">
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Adidas" name="attribute_value[2][]" id="bf-attr-2-1">
    </span>
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-2">
        <label class="bf-attr-val" for="bf-attr-2-1">Adidas</label>
    </span>
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-3"><span class="bf-count">2</span></span>
</div>

<div class="bf-attr-filter bf-attr-2 bf-row">
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="AJ Morgan" name="attribute_value[2][]" id="bf-attr-2-2">
    </span>
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-2">
        <label class="bf-attr-val" for="bf-attr-2-2">AJ Morgan</label>
    </span>
    <span class="bf-cell bf-c-3"><span class="bf-count">2</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: check this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: Sorting against what ?

Comment: sorting against the bf-count

Comment: @MajidAkbari, i need to sort numerically, not alphebetically

Comment: Use `parseInt(val, 10)` to sort numerically. That's it.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko This doesn't answer the real problem : OP wants to rearrange the elements

Comment: Yh, i want to rearrange the element in DESC order against the bf-count

Comment: @dystroy It does, combined with the link from the first comment.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko The answer accepted in the first link should not be used : it breaks all event handler bindings. It's a very bad solution when you have jQuery. But other answers are fine, you're right, I'll close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an alphabetical sort on the labels, you can do this :

```
$('.bf-attr-block-cont').append($('.bf-attr-block-cont .bf-attr-filter').sort(function(d1,d2){
   var s1 = $('label', d1).text().trim().toLowerCase(), 
       s2 = $('label', d2).text().trim().toLowerCase();
   if (s1===s2) return 0;
   return s1<s2 ? 1 : -1;
}));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/hejanoze/2/)

If you want to sort according to the .bf-count, do this :

```
$('.bf-attr-block-cont').append($('.bf-attr-block-cont .bf-attr-filter').sort(function(d1,d2){
   var s1 = parseFloat($('.bf-count', d1).text().trim()), 
       s2 = parseFloat($('.bf-count', d2).text().trim());
   if (s1===s2) return 0;
   return s1<s2 ? 1 : -1;
}));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/hejanoze/3/edit)

Note that those sorts don't break event handler bindings, contrary to naive solutions changing `innerHTML`.

Comment: the demo looks good, let me put them in my codes and will revert back

Comment: i tested on my code but it seems clash with the first div of .bf-attr-block-cont. So I tried to added in new class "brands" into the second div of .bf-attr-block-cont and replace the bf-attr-block-cont in your js code, but it doesn't sort .

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a minimal fiddle ?

Comment: I copied the codes from my site to your JS Bin and it seems working well.IS it because of the js conflict on my site?

Comment: @redcoder Hard to tell without more info. I'd suggest you [debug to see what happens](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).

Comment: please hv a look at my site at http://styles.my/thestar/index.php?route=product/category&path=61_107   I need to sort the BRAND section on the left menu...

Comment: dunno why the s1 and s2 value is NaN  NaN

Comment: Look at what's inside `$('.bf-count', d1).text()`.

Comment: realised I am using jQUery 1.7.1  , does the sort function available in ver 1.7.1 ?

Comment: here is my console log : console.log("here ",s1, s2, typeof(s1), $('.bf-count', d1).text());  . seems like the $('.bf-count', d1).text() is an empty string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54378/discussion-between-redcoder-and-dystroy).

Comment: dystroy, your code did working well, it was because of my bf-count value is empty on window.load, the value is injected using AJAX, that is why the bf-count was empty when page loaded.SO I put your sorting code in the AJAX call function that insert the bf-count value. Thanks for your time , credit goes to you.