# JQuery Sort Elements by Name

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm going to sort elements on my page by their names. This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/q3a9gmm6/1/

- I used `charCodeAt()` to be able to sort elements with UTF-8 values like Persian.

Sometimes I get wrong answers.
As you can see in the fiddle "Windows Phone" must be after "Windows Mobile" and "AMD" on top.

And I think that the code should be optimized to reduced the complexity.

What is the problem?

JQuery:

```
var itms_ind = 8;   

for (i = 0; i <= itms_ind; i++) {
    var first = $('.container div label:eq(0)');
    var first_char1_int = first.text().substr(0, 1).toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
    var first_char2_int = 
        first.text().substr(first.text().indexOf(' ') + 1, 1).toLowerCase().charCodeAt();

    for (j = 0; j <= itms_ind; j++)
        {
            $('.container div label').each(function() {
                var current = $(this);
                var current_char1_int = current.text().substr(0, 1).toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
                var current_char2_int = current.text().
                    substr(current.text().indexOf(' ') + 1, 1).toLowerCase().charCodeAt();

                if ((current_char1_int < first_char1_int)){
                    first.parent().before(current.parent());    
                } else
                if ((first_char1_int == current_char1_int)){
                    if (first_char2_int < current_char2_int)
                        current.parent().after(first.parent());
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Always put the relevant code **in** the question, not just buried away in a fiddle.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Comment: Here is my pick:- http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/2564/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a basic sorting like

```
var els = $('.container div').get();

els.sort(function(el1, el2){
    return $(el1).text().trim().localeCompare($(el2).text().trim())
})

$('.container').append(els)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2sf7ttz/)

Comment: +1, but I suspect the OP will also want to sort case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3a9gmm6/2/)

I totally change your solution for sorting.

```
var items = [];
$('.container div label').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    items.push($this.text());

});
items.sort();
```