# reverse a select list order

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

so I'm trying to reverse the order of a select element with multiple values with the following code:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
    var a = [];
    $('option').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).val());
    });

    a.reverse();

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    $('option').index[i].text(a[i]);
    }
```

and apparently I can't get the index of my option element to set it's value to the reverse order.

Comment: [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: The `index` property is a function not an array. You are looking for `.eq(i)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it a slightly different way too if you're interested:

```
//  Grab the options
var $select = $('select');
var options = $select.find('option');

// turn the nodelist into an array and reverse it
options = [].slice.call(options).reverse();

// empty the select
$select.empty();

// add each option back
$.each(options, function (i, el) {
  $select.append($(el));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9t65qmns/10/)

Answer (score 2):

The `index` property is a function not an array. However, you are looking for `.eq(i)`, or better, [pass a function to `.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function):

```
$('option').text(function(i) {
    return a[i];
});
```

Alternative, you coukd change the order of the elements itself, see [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134976/218196)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.eq(1)` as suggested by @FelixKing in the comments, that should do it:

```
$('option:eq(' + i + ')').text( a[i] );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to reorder `option` tags itself I think, not just reordering the `text` ex: if one element is selected by default, or having some `data` attributes, you will mess up it, thus following solution would work the best:

```
$('.reversed option').each(function () {
      $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

This way we iterate through the options and prepend each of them to the `select` tag, finally we get them in reversed order

More optimal *(for performance)* way:

```
var select = $('.reversed');

select.find('option').each(function(){
    $(this).prependTo(select);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pk4z72o/