# Need function to sort generated <li> in htm page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to sort out a movie listing webpage that lists all the movies in sequence according to their #TITLE#.  Currently the software automatically generates a web page based off of a template file.  Below is the portion of the coding in the template file that lists the movies:

```
 <!-- Latest additions-->
#LATEST_ADDITIONS_START#
<div class="header">Movie Cover Listings</div>
#LATEST_ADDITIONS_TEMPLATE_START#
<li>
    <a href="movies/#INDEX#.htm">
    <table style="display: inline; border: 0; cellspacing: 1;">
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center"><img border="0" src="covers/#COVER#.jpg" width="#WIDTH#" height="#HEIGHT#"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td width="80" height="100" align="center" valign="top">#TITLE#</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
</li>
#LATEST_ADDITIONS_TEMPLATE_END#
<div class="link_latest"><tr>#LATEST_ADDITIONS#</tr></div>
#LATEST_ADDITIONS_END#

<!-- All movies -->
```

This is what the programs generates from the database using the template file:

```
<!-- Latest additions-->

<div class="header">Movie Cover Listings</div>

<div class="link_latest"><tr>

<li>
    <a href="movies/2.htm">
    <table style="display: inline; border: 0; cellspacing: 1;">
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center"><img border="0" src="covers/000002.jpg" width="90" height="135"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td width="80" height="100" align="center" valign="top">3 Days to Kill</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="movies/1.htm">
    <table style="display: inline; border: 0; cellspacing: 1;">
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center"><img border="0" src="covers/000001.jpg" width="89" height="135"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td width="80" height="100" align="center" valign="top">300: Rise of an Empire 3D</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</a>
</li>
</tr></div>


<!-- All movies -->
```

As you can see it orders it automatically in numerical descending order by #INDEX# file name.  I want to order it alphabetically by #TITLE# name.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Well answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all your values from the backend database which is show all values in Descending Order by DESC file_name.

If you want to show all data order by title name, you simply needs to do this:

SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY title_name DESC

Comment: Just change ORDER BY file name to ORDER BY title_name and if u want to show in Descending Order then after ORDER BY title_name put DESC. Follow above instructions then I am sure you will get it work..

Answer (score 0):

If this can be done on backend, I would suggest using `ORDER BY` clause:

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY title`

This would be more efficient than using it on frontend.
But since the question has tags related to frontend only:

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if(typeof ul == "string")
    ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  // Get the list items and setup an array for sorting
  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var vals = [];

  // Populate the array
  for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

  // Sort it
  vals.sort();

  // Sometimes you gotta DESC
  if(sortDescending)
    vals.reverse();

  // Change the list on the page
  for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}

//Easy to use...

sortUnorderedList("ID_OF_LIST");
```

**Reference:** [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: I can only edit the front end (or the template web page).  The program generates all the #""# output data and the program translates the web page template to a webpage.  This is why I'm stuck.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't tell.  I'm still kinda a newbie to advanced javascript.  I can get basic javascript and even a bit advanced as well as working with a fresh page. But when it comes to rewriting a page(s) layout (especially those with no java in them to start) using javascript I'm a bit lost.