# jQuery: how to parse a <ul> list?

Tags: jquery

I have, for example,  the following list:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a language-id="2" language-code="de" href="#">Allemand</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="9" language-code="en" href="#">Anglais</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="28" language-code="ca" href="#">Catalan</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="11" language-code="zh" href="#">Chinois</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="4" language-code="es" href="#">Espagnol</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="1" language-code="fr" href="#">Français</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="10" language-code="nl" href="#">Hollandais</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="21" language-code="it" href="#">Italien</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="12" language-code="ja" href="#">Japonais</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="7" language-code="pl" href="#">Polonais</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="5" language-code="pt" href="#">Portugais</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="6" language-code="ru" href="#">Russe</a></li>
    <li><a language-id="29" language-code="cs" href="#">Tchèque</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to insert a new language in alphabetical order. So I know to use insertAfter() or insertBefore(), but I don't see how to parse the list to compare the new language with each item of the list.
How can I do?

Regards,

Comment: You should use data attributes (`data-*`) instead of making up your own. And more importantly, what have you tried? You didn't post any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.each()`

```
$('#dropdown-menu').each(function () {
   // use $(this) as an li
});
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Good, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [SO question: How to sort a list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery).

Append the new items to the list (order doesn't matter at this point).  When you're finished, use [array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to reorder the list.

```js
var menu = $('.dropdown-menu');

menu.append('<li><a language-id="29" language-code="cs" href="#">Tchèque</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="6" language-code="ru" href="#">Russe</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="5" language-code="pt" href="#">Portugais</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="4" language-code="es" href="#">Espagnol</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="10" language-code="nl" href="#">Hollandais</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="12" language-code="ja" href="#">Japonais</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="11" language-code="zh" href="#">Chinois</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="9" language-code="en" href="#">Anglais</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="1" language-code="fr" href="#">Français</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="21" language-code="it" href="#">Italien</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="2" language-code="de" href="#">Allemand</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="7" language-code="pl" href="#">Polonais</a></li>');
menu.append('<li><a language-id="28" language-code="ca" href="#">Catalan</a></li>');

$('.dropdown-menu li').sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
.appendTo('.dropdown-menu');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="dropdown-menu">
</ul>
```

Comment: very interesting solution so I give you +1 but the answer of Shahen Kosyan was ok for me. ;)