# Sort an unordered list alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to sort an unordered list alphabetically. I've tried many different javascript solutions, not one of them worked (tested in Safari and Chrome). This is the code I would like to use:

```js
var activeLanguage = "de"

function sortUL(selector) {
  var $ul = $(selector);
  $ul.find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
    var upA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var upB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
  }).appendTo(selector);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  sortUL("#WoodList");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="WoodList">
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Catv</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Car</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cat2</li>
  <li>Apple4</li>
  <li>Banana1</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
</ul>
```

The list remains unsorted in the browser. Why is it not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vzbgzexc/

Make sure that you're loading jQuery. It doesn't look like anywhere in your code that you're loading jQuery, yet you're using `$`. You're likely receiving an error in your browser's console similar to this:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Insert:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I transferred the java script code to an external .js file and added your piece of code in the header - works finally!

Comment: Do you load jQuery before you call the external .js file?

Comment: yes, first the jquery load and then the link to the external .js file