# UL and LI with jQuery 3.2.1 running error

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-lists

[I have this working link where it is displaied the outcome I want](https://jsfiddle.net/mac4kent/wzej67gj/1/)

However when I insert my code to Dreamweaver cc 2018 it doesn't work.
I use the 3.2.1 version of jquery `jquery-3.2.1.js`.

In my jsfiddle the selection is sorted alphabetically while in my page it doesn't.

```js
var mylist = $('#list');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
mylist.empty().append(listitems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
<li>h</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>i</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>l</li>
<li>j</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>g</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>k</li>
<li>n</li>
<li>m</li>
</ul>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What kinda `error` ?

Comment: So it is working? Or not?

Comment: Maybe your problem is when your script is read as when your html is rendered. Have you tried inserting your javascript code inside a document ready? I can't think of something else with the information you are providing.

Comment: I am done see below answer are right.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned to my comment you problem probably is the timing of your html rendering and the javascript execution. You could try inserting your javascript code inside a document ready like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var mylist = $('#list');
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
    })
    mylist.empty().append(listitems);
});
```

Comment: You are so smart now it work for sure last one $( document ) . . . finallllllly. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the part $(document .... finallllly)? What do you mean with that? Any way I am glad I helped and I hope my answer was what you needed.

Comment: I mean you did put $( document ).ready(function() { . . . yes I check on DreamWeaver cc it work.

Comment: I' m glad it worked then. If it is what you needed then you could accept my answer if you are not expecting for somithg other. Cheers.