# I'm getting json data through an API and displaying it in a table using jquery. How to add sort function?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting json data through an API and displaying it in a table using jquery. The data in table is being dynamically updated. How to add sort function to the table ex - sort by price, when I click on the price column?

we are getting details api (**https://coincap.io/front**) in json format and display in table through jQuery. but how to add sorting functionality individual column (ex: Price, Market Capitalization).

```js
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
     url: "https://coincap.io/front"
    })
    .done(function(data) {

         for(let i=0;i<100;i++)
         {
             let price;
              if(data[i]['price'] > 0.1)
            {
                price = data[i]['price'].toFixed(2);
            }
            else
            {
                price = data[i]['price'].toFixed(5);
            }
             
                       
             $('#coinValues').append(
                
                 '<tr id='+ data[i]['short'] + '><td class="name" style="text-align:left !important;padding-left:8px !important;"><span class="icon" style="background-position:center;vertical-align: middle;padding-right:3px;display:inline-block;height: 25px;width:25px;background:url('+data[i]["short"].toLowerCase() +'.png) no-repeat;background-size:contain;"></span> <a style="color:#5386C5;" target="_blank" href ="'+data[i]['short'] +'">' + data[i]['long'] + '</td>' +
                 '<td class="price">$'+ price + '</td>' +
                 '<td class="cap24hrChange">'+ data[i]['cap24hrChange'] + '%</td>' +
                 '<td class="mktcap">$'+ Math.round(data[i]['mktcap']).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '</td>' +
                 '<td class="volume">$'+ data[i]['volume'].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '</td>' +
                 '<td class="supply">'+ data[i]['supply'].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") +' ' + data[i]['short'] + '</td>' +
                 '</tr>'
                 
                 );
            $('#' +data[i]['short'] +' .cap24hrChange').css('color','#093');
            $('#' +data[i]['short'] +' .cap24hrChange:contains("-")').css('color','#d14836');
         }
        
    });
            
    });
```

```css
.paging-nav {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.paging-nav a {
  margin: auto 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  background: #91b9e6;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.paging-nav .selected-page {
  background: #187ed5;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav>li>a{
    padding:0px;
}

     .coins_table_container {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }
    
    .coins_table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background: white;
         width: 100%; 
        color: #717171;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        border-radius:7px !important;
        
    }
    
    
    .coins_table tr td {
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
       margin-right: 8px !important;
       padding-right:8px !important;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #717171;
        text-align: right;
        line-height:45px;
    }
    
    .coins_table tr th {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding-right: 8px !important;
    margin-right: 8px !important;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #717171;
    /* text-align: center; */
    line-height: 22px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
     
    .selectlist{
        margin-bottom:15px;
        width:50%;
        float:left;
        margin-top:7px;
    }
    .srch{
       float: left;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    }
    
    .new-topz{
        margin-top:30px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    .cname{
        width:14% !important;
    }
    
    .cprice{
    width:10% !important;
    }
    
    .cmarket{
    width:16% !important;
    }
    
    .cvol{
    width:15% !important;
    }
    
    .cchange{
    width:12% !important;
    }
    
    .cavailbl{
    width:21% !important;
    }
    .container{
        width:93%;
        max-width:1600px;
    }
    #sidebar-container{
            width: 26%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top:50px;
    }
    #currency-side{
        width: 70%;
    margin-right: 0px;
        padding-right: 25px;
    }
    #sidebar{
        border-left: 2px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
    }
    #sidebar .widget_display_topics ul{
       
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
            font-family: 'Montserrat',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1em;
    }
    
    #rfw_dock-2{
        display:none !important;
    }
    
    #text-5{
     display:none !important;
    }
    
    .button-static{
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <table id="coin_table" class="coins_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="cname" style="text-align:left !important;padding-left:8px !important">Name</th>
                                <th class="cprice">Price</th>
                                <th class="cchange">Change (%24hr)</th>
                                <th class="cmarket">Market Capitalization</th>
                                <th class="cvol">24 Hour Volume</th>
                                <th class="cavailbl">Availability Supply</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                      
                        <tbody id="coinValues">
                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
  var eTable=""
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
  {
    eTable += "<tr>";
    eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['id']+"</td>";
    eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Name']+"</td>";
    eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Type']+"</td>";
    eTable += "</tr>";
  }

  $('#example').append(eTable);
```