# Split jQuery list into two alphabetically ordered parts by class

Tags: jquery, list, unordered

I'd like list elements with class 'active' to be ordered alphabetically at the top of a list, with the remainder of the list underneath ordered separately.  In other words,

```
<li><label><span>zz</span></label></li>
<li class='active'><label><span>rr</span></label></li>
<li class='active'><label><span>bb</span></label></li>
<li><label><span>hh</span></label></li>
<li><label><span>ii</span></label></li>
<li class='active'><label><span>yy</span></label></li>
<li><label><span>kk</span></label></li>
<li><label><span>mm</span></label></li>
```

results in..

```
bb
rr
yy
hh
ii
kk
mm
zz
```

I think I've got the right approach but I can't seem to get this to work.  Something to do with the append I think.  Can anyone help me get over the last hurdle?  https://jsfiddle.net/Lcz47b9y/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="rootUl">
    <li><label><span>zz</span></label></li>
    <li class='active'><label><span>rr</span></label></li>
    <li class='active'><label><span>bb</span></label></li>
    <li><label><span>hh</span></label></li>
    <li><label><span>ii</span></label></li>
    <li class='active'><label><span>yy</span></label></li>
    <li><label><span>kk</span></label></li>
    <li><label><span>mm</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

.

```
var myli = $('#rootUl li.active label').children('span').detach().sort(sortByText);

$('#rootUl').append($(myli))

function sortByText(a, b) {
    var first = $.trim($(a).text());
    var second = $.trim($(b).text());
    return first.localeCompare(second);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134983/2943218

Comment: Yes I have - but was still having problems extracting just part of the list and putting it back in the place I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can amend your `sort()` logic to first compare the classes on the elements, and then if they match compare them by text. Try this:

```js
$('#rootUl li').sort(function(a, b) {
  var $a = $(a), $b = $(b);
  if ($a.hasClass('active') && !$b.hasClass('active')) {
    return -1;
  } else if (!$a.hasClass('active') && $b.hasClass('active')) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return $a.text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($b.text().toUpperCase());
}).appendTo('#rootUl');
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="rootUl">
  <li><label><span>zz</span></label></li>
  <li class='active'><label><span>rr</span></label></li>
  <li class='active'><label><span>bb</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>hh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>ii</span></label></li>
  <li class='active'><label><span>yy</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>kk</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>mm</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah now I see where I was going wrong.  Great solution.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that the `sort()` logic can be made less verbose, but it gets harder to understand, so I left it clear to read

Answer (score 1):

Detach the `li`s, not their inner `<span>`s - then, in the `.sort` function, access the span text, and then use `prependTo` to insert at the top.

It looks like you want to sort *both* the `.active`s and the non-`.active`s, so put that logic into your compare function too, by subtracting calls of `hasClass`:

```js
const getSpanText = elm => $(elm).find('span').text();

$('#rootUl li')
  .detach()
  .sort(sortByText)
  .prependTo('#rootUl');

function sortByText(a, b) {
  return $(b).hasClass('active') - $(a).hasClass('active')
    || getSpanText(a).localeCompare(getSpanText(b));
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="rootUl">
  <li><label><span>zz</span></label></li>
  <li class='active'><label><span>rr</span></label></li>
  <li class='active'><label><span>bb</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>hh</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>ii</span></label></li>
  <li class='active'><label><span>yy</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>kk</span></label></li>
  <li><label><span>mm</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that the non-`.active` elements need to be sorted too

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, yes, this works too although Rory's solution was the first to fully work.