# How to sort contents of div alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alphabetical

I have a dropdown menu with a long list of items and I want it to appear in alphabetical order.

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#john" id="john-link" class="anchor">
          <img src="images/logos/chelsea.png">John</a>
          <a href="#paul" id="paul-link" class="anchor">
          <img src="images/logos/tfc.png">Paul</a>
          <a href="#umar" id="umar-link" class="anchor">
          <img src="images/logos/realmadrid.png">Umar</a>
          <a href="#mass" id="mass-link" class="anchor">
          <img src="images/logos/inter.png">Mass</a>
          <a href="#carlos" id="carlos-link" class="anchor">
          <img src="images/logos/leverkusen.png">Carlos</a>
          <a href="#colla" id="colla-link" class="anchor">
        </div>
```

Is there a way with jQuery or javascript to sort my content alphabetically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: I'd rather not change my content to a list if I don't have to, since I'll have to change a lot of my styling

Comment: You can use whichever HTML structure you like. In your case, the list would be a series of `<a>` elements. The idea is to make an array of the elements, [sort them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), and then replace them on the page.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid just moving the inner html, you can use the approach below.

```
function sortMe(parent, children) {
    children.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.innerText < b.innerText) {
            return -1
        }
        if (a.innerText > b.innerText) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    children.detach().appendTo(parent);
}
```

Specify the parent and children (the elements used for sorting - in this case it is the `innerText` of the `a` tags):

```
let parent = $("#myDropdown");
let children = $("#myDropdown").children("a");
```

Then call the function with the proper args:

```
sortMe(parent,children);
```

You shouldn't need to change the HTML for this approach to work.