# Sorting select list of options alphabetically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

please can you help me to populate my select list alphabetically.

Here is the code I have so far:-

```
$.getJSON("php/countryBorders.geo.json", (data) => {
  $select.html("");
  

  for (let i = 0; i < data["features"].length; i++) {
    
    $select.append(
      '<option value="' +
        data["features"][i]['properties']["iso_a2"] +
        '">' +
        data["features"][i]["properties"]["name"]
       
    );  
   
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to sort anything

Comment: I would like to sort the list aphabetically by name, but am unsure how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.getJSON("php/countryBorders.geo.json", (data) => {
  $select.html("");
  
  const features = data["features"].sort((a,b) => {
    return (
      (a.properties.name < b.properties.name && -1) ||
      (a.properties.name > b.properties.name && 1) ||
      0
    ); 
  });
  
  features.forEach(feature => {
    $select.append(`<option value="${feature.properties.iso_a2}">${feature.properties.name}</option>`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Extract the text and value of each `option` tag into an array of objects. ANd sort the array. Then update the `option` elements with the array contents in order

```
var opts = $('select');
var arr = opts.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
opts.each(function(i, o) {
  o.value = arr[i].v;
  $(o).text(arr[i].t);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below logic for sorting, you just need to use `name` value instead of `a` and `b` while comparing (from the the array which you want to sort).

```js
var data  = ["ball","cat","elephant","dog","apple"];
console.log(data);
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if(a > b) return 1;
    if(a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
});
console.log(data);
```