# jQuery drag an drop sort list parent/child

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

does anyone know about a jquery plugin that is able to sort a parent/child tree?
for ex:

```
- Cat 1
    child 1
    child 2
    child 3
- Cat2
    child 2-1
    child 2-2
```

i have to sort the child items inside the SAME Cat and save the order to DB with AJAX. Also, i need to sort Cat aswell. In that case, all the child items should follow it's parent Cat. 
Does anyone know a plugin that does this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. Do you want to sort the entire list, then resort after you drag and drop a child? There are many answers on sorting, you will have to adapt them to suit your needs:

1. [What is the easiest way to order a <UL>/<OL> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)
2. [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/jquery-sort-list-items-alphabetically)
3. or check out [Tinysort](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort).

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin for drag and drop sort...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/draganddropsort

I'm not sure whether it deals with the tree-view of options or not... I suspect it could if required! It certainly allows you to turn any collection of HTML elements into a sortable section.