# Sort Divs every X amount of seconds with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have 5 divs, each having count down timers. The following numbers would obviously be be divided by `<br/>`'s , but for the sake of the example I am trying to be as clear as possible :-)

Example before sort

```
4.39
3.45
2.11
3.56
1.11
```

Example after sort

```
4.39
3.56
3.45
2.11
1.11
```

And each countdown counts to 0 obviously. I had in mind, that when a timer reaches 0, that div is sorted automatically sorted and put down in the last position, and then starts again.

I was looking at Jquery's website, and the ones I found are drag related, meaning you have to click on the DIV, and move it yourself. I would like to achieve that animation automatically, by a method that sorts out DIVS according to the timer.

Anyone have a code snippet, one which I didn't find already, that I might find handy? :-)

All help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: use a list ( `<ul>` and `<li>`) and sort them with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your list using normal jquery selectors. Put all the elements inside a single `ul` or something and read then out using vanilla jquery.

For sorting, you can use the [sort method](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) available for Javascript arrays.

To move the `li` items into place, you can use either reposition then with some animation (perhaps using the [position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) function in jquery-ui) or simply replace the contents of the `ul` with a sort list of `li`'s

Finally, to do this repeatedly, you can use the [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) function.

It might also be possible to tie in some triggers to the jquery-ui [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) and then just call that from your `setInterval` expression. I haven't tried this though.

Comment: Hmmm I'll try your suggestion out, and paste my solution

Comment: Hi there, I came up with a solution, and is found on http://blog.stephenborg.com/?p=219. I cannot however seem to do an animation of setPosition of X and Y. But anyways, if you would like to see my way of doing it you can download the source code from my post. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

1. Iterate over the `DIVs` or list elements
2. read the text
3. convert them to a `double`
4. add each value to an array
5. Sort the array
6. Create a string of HTML with jQuery
7. replace the content of the container with the new list

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the DIVs and then append the sorted DIV element one by one to a HTML container (such as another DIV holding all these sub-DIVs).

Comment: It looks like a list. I'd suggest putting `li`'s into a `ul` rather than going the divititis route.