# How to make a menu using UL LI sortable in jquery

Tags: jquery

How you i make my menu sortable so i can move there position around

```
 <ul id="nav-one" class="nav">
  <li> Home</a></li>

 <li>
Members
<ul>
<li><a href="?p=view_users" target="_self">All Users</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

can someone lead me down the right path please

Thank you,

Comment: How do you want to sort it? These links might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/jquery-sort-list-items-alphabetically

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery UI Sortable for that. [See the demo here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

> The jQuery UI Sortable plugin makes
>   selected elements sortable by dragging
>   with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

The sortable plugin provides that feature. They also provide some source code examples.