# Move a div at the end of the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<li>This is 
  <div class="item1">item1</div>
  <div class="item3">item3</div>
  <div class="item2">item2</div>
a test</li>​
```

I would like to arrange the li as follows `<li>This is a test | div item1 | div item2 | div item3 </li>`

Is it possible to do that without using javascript? Only css? If not can you provide a sample in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of your CSS and explain the desired result with an image or so? Please, considere posting your code on http://jsfiddle.net and we will take a look.

Comment: Where did "the whole text" come from?

Comment: Try and use the following links: [Easiest way to order a ul ol in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery) and [Sort a list alphabetically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery).

Comment: @Eric in my example `This is a test`

Comment: why "the whole text" is initially splitted inside your `li`?

Comment: @salamis: Then why not give that as your expected result!?

Comment: @Eric because it is derived from a parsed `.bib` file. And the user might enter any element at any position!

Comment: @salamis: No, I meant why give us an example output that doesn't match the example input?

Comment: is this it ? http://jsfiddle.net/LceqM/

Comment: @Esailija yes mate. Can you post it as an answer? Even if it is not css I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LceqM/

```
var li = document.getElementById("theli"),
    textNodes = [], first;

var elem = li.firstChild;

while( elem ) {
    if( elem.nodeType === 3 ) textNodes.push(elem);
    elem = elem.nextSibling;
}

if( textNodes.length ) {
    first = textNodes.shift();
    li.insertBefore( first, li.firstChild );

    while( textNodes.length ) {
        li.insertBefore( textNodes.pop(), first.nextSibling );   
    }
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

you can change inner Html of a html tag by using following js code:

```
document.getElementById("yourliid").innerHTML = "new value of html that you want"
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd make more sense to set your HTML to:

```
<li>This is a test
  <div class="item1">item1</div>
  <div class="item3">item3</div>
  <div class="item2">item2</div>
</li>​
```

Then apply

```
​li div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1ex;
    border-left: 1px solid black;     
}​
```

---

Option two: Add a wrapper div around your HTML:

```
<li>This is
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item1">item1</div>
    <div class="item3">item3</div>
    <div class="item2">item2</div>
  </div>
  a test
</li>​
```

```css
​li .container {
    float: right;
}​
​li .container div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5tDc/ Can I somehow do what is described above with only css?

Comment: @salamis: Why does your HTML look like that? Can you add a wrapper div around the three inner divs?

Comment: No mate. I explained you before. Because I parse a bib file.

Comment: @salamis: What is a `.bib` file? What do you parse it with? Why don't you move the html as part of the parsing step, rather than do it in javascript later?