# Sort navigation menu in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, menu, html-lists

I want to sort the navigation menu with jQuery. The structure of nav menu is

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
     <a class="link">one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
     <a class="link">two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
     <a class="link">three</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
     <a class="link">four</a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

I want to sort on the basis of the inner html of `a` tag. There is by default `sort` function in jquery. but it only sorts the strings. How I can sort the menu

Comment: This link may help you 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery

Comment: Its just about the `ul li`, but there is an anchor tag in my code. I have to order on basis of anchor tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var items = $('.menu li').get();
items.sort(function(a,b){ 
  var keyA = $(a).find('a').text();
  var keyB = $(b).find('a').text();

  if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
var ul = $('.menu');
ul.empty();
$.each(items, function(i, li){
  ul.append(li);
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZtPF/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedList = jQuery('.menu > li').sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.children[0].innerHTML > b.children[0].innerHTML) ? 1 : -1;
});

jQuery('.menu').html(sortedList);
```

Comment: This is really a much better solution than the accepted answer.