# How do I sort an unordered list with jquery tsort when I only have the ul as a variable?

Tags: jquery, sorting

The normal syntax for using tsort to sort a ul would be:

```
$('ul>li').tsort();
```

I have the ul as a variable from code similar to:

```
var myul=$('#mydiv').find('ul');
```

How can I use the myul variable later in my code with tsort?

Note that I have simplified the details a lot here, suffice to say that it would not be easy to identify the ul without using the variable when I am ready to tsort, so I am wondering if I can get to it this way round instead.

Comment: Try looking at this [What is the easiest way to order a <UL>/<OL> in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)

Comment: Just `myul.tsort()` or `myul.children().tsort()` -- not sure what `tsort` is.

Comment: @user1477388 - Still needs the ul followed by li in the $(), not as a variable like I have it

Comment: @Jon myul.tsort() would sort the ul nodes not the li nodes within the ul ... but adding .children() does the trick

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Can't you simply do `$('#mydiv').find('ul').children('li')`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I didn't realise that myul.children() was equivalent to $('ul>li') and it wasn't given as an example in the tsort docs, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @BenHolness: Ah, good! I just posted that as an answer, since I'd found the `tsort` docs (hadn't heard of it before) and it looked like it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the `tinysort` plugin, if you have `myul`, you have access to its children. [The docs](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) say you'd just do this:

```
myul.children().tsort();
```

Completely gratuitous example (I wanted to play with tinysort): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/OdelUhUR/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/OdelUhUR/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/src/jquery.tinysort.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>In a second, the list below will sort itself.</p>
  <div id="mydiv">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      var myul = $("#mydiv").find("ul");
      myul.children().tsort();
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks! In the tsort docs, it doesn't give an example with .children() and I didn't realise that was equivalent.

Comment: :_) this is a stupid question it's so obvious.  I didn't think thats what you wanted.  Thanks for downvoting my attempt to help you

Comment: @user1477388 in my question I specifically said "How can I use the myul variable later in my code with tsort?". Your answer did not use that and I knew as explained in my question how to do it the way you answered.

Comment: also, @user1477388 it may have been obvious to you, but it wasn't to me. We all learn new things about how stuff works all the time and until you learn something, you don't know it. Asking about something that you don't know does not make it a stupid question.

Comment: You don't have to explain "there are no stupid questions to me" but I'm just saying, the answer is so obvious it almost goes without saying.  I was just mad at myself that I didn't realize how obvious it was!