# Sort multilevel list menu alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I need to sort a multilevel html list alphabetically.
What I have:

```
<ul>

<li>
   <a href="#">B Link</a>
   <ul class="sub-cat-list">
      <li>
         <a href="#">X sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">A Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">X sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>

<li>
   <a href="#">A Link</a>
   <ul class="sub-cat-list">
      <li>
         <a href="#">H sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">X Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Z sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">B sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">V Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">J sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">U sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>

<li>
   <a href="#">X Link</a>
   <ul class="sub-cat-list">
      <li>
         <a href="#">C sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">L Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Y sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Y sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">A sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">G Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">T sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">R sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Every link and every block list should be sorted. 
So what I need:

```
<ul>

<li>
   <a href="#">A Link</a>
   <ul class="sub-cat-list">
      <li>
         <a href="#">B sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">J sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">U sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">V Sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">H sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">D sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">X Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Z sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>

   </ul>
</li>

<li>
   <a href="#">B Link</a>
   <ul class="sub-cat-list">
      <li>
         <a href="#">X sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">A Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">X sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>


<li>
   <a href="#">X Link</a>
   <ul class="sub-cat-list">
      <li>
         <a href="#">A sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">A sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">R sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">T sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
         <a href="#">C sub link </a>
         <ul class="sub-cat-list">
            <li><a href="#">L Sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Y sub sub link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Y sub sub link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>

   </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

There's a code for sorting:

```
$.fn.sortList = function() {
    var mylist = $(this);
    var listitems = $('li', mylist).get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $.each(listitems, function(i, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
}
```

I try to use it with this way:

```
$("ul.sub-cat-list >li >ul").each(function(){
    $(this).sortList();
})
```

But the problem is it applies to the second `.sub-cat-list` class only and I can't 
understand what selector I should use for the whole menu to get the result I need.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alenka92/ft0s9y4L/3/)

Hope for your help.
Thanks.

Comment: [Does it help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)

Comment: Each `ul` will have the same number of `li`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `var listitems = $('li', mylist).get();` to `var listitems = $('> li', mylist).get();` in your sortList function it will only look at the `<li>` tags for the current list.

Then you can sort all the lists by calling

```
$("ul").each(function(){
    $(this).sortList();
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y8zmkjt/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @NagarajS suggestion ([order ul in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)), I made some changes for your case.

Try this:

```js
$('.menu ul').each(function () {
    var ul = $(this);
    var items = $(this).children().get();
    items.sort(function (a, b) {
        var keyA = $(a).text();
        var keyB = $(b).text();

        if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    $.each(items, function (i, li) {
        ul.append(li);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">B Link</a>

            <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                <li> <a href="#">X sub link </a>

                    <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                        <li><a href="#">A Sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">C sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">D sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">X sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">A Link</a>

            <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                <li> <a href="#">H sub link </a>

                    <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                        <li><a href="#">X Sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">D sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">F sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Z sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">B sub link </a>

                    <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                        <li><a href="#">V Sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">J sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">O sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">U sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">X Link</a>

            <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                <li> <a href="#">C sub link </a>

                    <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                        <li><a href="#">L Sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">O sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Y sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Y sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">A sub link </a>

                    <ul class="sub-cat-list">
                        <li><a href="#">G Sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">T sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">R sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">A sub sub link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Every single `ul` inside the `.menu` div will be sorted, starting from the top level to the lowest level.