# Bootstrap Select List

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to sort this dropdown selector by alphabetical letters

```
<div class="container">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" >
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">d</option>
<option value="3">b</option>
<option value="4">c</option>
</select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some javascript code, here is "my" solution, this is done with jQuery.

```
var items = $('#select option').get();
items.sort(function(a,b){
  var keyA = $(a).text();
  var keyB = $(b).text();

  if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
var select = $('#select');
$.each(items, function(i, option){
select.append(option);
});
```

And you should add an `ID` (or class, or something) to the `<select>`

```
 <select id="select" class="form-control" >
```

Source: [What is the easiest way to order a <UL>/<OL> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbe2e665/

Answer (score 1):

[This Codepen](http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/kCwvJ) might be just what you are looking for.

**Note**: it requires jQuery. Put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

In the `head` of your page.