# Bootstrap select picker automatically sorting based on key

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using Bootstrap [selectpicker](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for populating the select box.

I have the data in the DB table like this,

```
*cId*  *CountryName*
1      Australia
2      Belgium
3      Canada
4      India
5      Zimbabwe
6      Brazil
```

What I am doing is ordering the data based on `countryName` and populating cId as `option` element's key and `countryName` as `option` element's value

```
function loadJSONtoSelectBox(selector, options)
{
   $(selector).selectpicker();
   $.each(options, function(key, value) {
       $('<option data-tokens="'+value+'" value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>').appendTo(selector);
       $(selector).focus();
  });

  $(selector).selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

But internally it is sorting based on `option's` value attribute i.e it is showing Brazil(cid is 6) at the end instead of after Belgium, what is the hack to solve this issue?
how can I turn off that internal sorting?

Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/14a3h2bt/

For more reference check my comment here: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1476

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697185/bootstrap-select-list), and it might be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look to [bootstrap-select.js](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js) you can see in the

***createLi: function () {***

the option elements of the select are selected and trasformed in li tag using:

***this.$element.find('option').each(function (index) {***

So, there is no sorting on values (i.e.: keys or *cId*). **There is no sorting at all.**

A proof of this is a static select with the option rearranged according to what you want to see (Bazil is at the 3th position even if the value  is 6):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
  
  
  $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
    console.log('Value is: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value +
                ' Text is: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" tabindex="-98">
    <option data-tokens="Australia" value="1">Australia</option>
    <option data-tokens="Belgium" value="2">Belgium</option>
    <option data-tokens="Brazil" value="6">Brazil</option>
    <option data-tokens="Canada" value="3">Canada</option>
    <option data-tokens="India" value="4">India</option>
    <option data-tokens="Zimbabwe" value="5">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Said that, I may suggest you to sort the options (in this case on client side, but you can do this directly on your server side):

```js
function loadJSONtoSelectBox(selector, options) {
  $(selector).selectpicker({});
  $.each(options, function (key, value) {
    $('<option>', {'data-tokens': value, 'value': key, 'text': value}).appendTo(selector);
    $(selector).focus();
  });

  //
  // Sort Items by Text
  //
  $(selector + ' option').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent);
  }).appendTo(selector);

  $(selector).selectpicker('val', '1').selectpicker('refresh');
}

$(function () {
  var opt = {
    '1': 'Australia',
    '2': 'Belgium',
    '3': 'Canada',
    '4': 'India',
    '5': 'Zimbabwe',
    '6': 'Brazil'
  };
  loadJSONtoSelectBox('.selectpicker', opt);

  $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
    console.log('Value is: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value +
                ' Text is: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
</select>
```

Comment: I am doing `ordery by countryName` and loading it dynamically, Try loading it dynamically using json, and you'll see the different results. I have posted the issue in repo too https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1476

Comment: it ain't object it's JSON, I'm getting it with ajax request and what is this `a.textContent.localeCompare`

Comment: I suggest to take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order.  never rely on how object properties  are ordered. Do it by yourself.

Comment: Yes, it's a json. But in js it is in any case an object.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm obliged to remove some comments, it's up to SO. If you do:  typeof data.examCities1 you obtain as a result object. So data.examCities1 is an object in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I have just wrote some JavaScript for your solution.

For this we can do like sorting things. So i was sorting your content alphabetical.

Please take a look in [**`Fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dynamic_Designer/shwvo7fu/). Hope it will help you. :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = $('.dropdown-menu .text');
  var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
    return {
      t: $(o).text(),
      v: o.value
    };
  }).get();
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t.toUpperCase() > o2.t.toUpperCase() ? 1 : o1.t.toUpperCase() < o2.t.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 0;
  });
  options.each(function(i, o) {
    o.value = arr[i].v;
    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
  });
});
```

Comment: question is not regarding `option`, it's regarding `selectpicker` plugin