# Sorting HTML ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

So my question is it possible to sort list items by number in strong tag, when i try with JavaScript code below it sort numbers and but get them out of div tag.
(I use these js code for sorting by Name and it work fine when b = ...(LI))
HTML:

```
<section>
<button class="sortbynum" onclick="sortListNum()">Sort By Num</button>
<ul id="sort">
    <li> 
       <div><h2>Name</h2></div>  
       <a href=""><img src=""/></a> 
       <div><span>Something:...</span></div>
       <div><span>something:...</span></div>
       <div><span>HHJS: <strong class="sortNum">456</strong></span></div>
    </li>
    <li>again</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sortListNum() {var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch, dir,switchcount = 0;list = document.getElementById("sort");switching = true;dir = "asc"; while (switching) {switching = false;b = list.getElementsByClassName("sortNum");
for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
  shouldSwitch = false;
  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (shouldSwitch) {
  b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
  switching = true;
  switchcount ++;
} else {
  if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
    dir = "desc";
    switching = true;
  }
}}}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Good luck! Side note, We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: You have the question tagged as jQuery, so take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery.  I would add classes to each bit you'd like to sort by and then the sort function can easily target that class within the li

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to extrapolate from this that you're asking if you can extract text from inline elements.

You can select them like anything else, but it's a little more interesting that.

`innerHTML` returns HTML, which can be HTML or plain text or both.

`innerText` returns plain text.

`textContent` returns all of the contained plain text concatenated into one string, only separated by newline characters when the next element is on a new line.

Since you have more text than just the number within the element, just select the `strong` tag and call `innerText`:

```
document.querySelector('#sort .sortNum').innerText
```

Comment: I dont need to extract text, i need to sort those list items by number whitch is in strong tag.